# Prevent redirection of XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Is it possible to prevent the browser from following redirects when sending XMLHttpRequest-s (i.e. to get the redirect status code back and handle it myself)?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Not according to [the W3C standard for the XMLHttpRequest object](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/xhr/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#infrastructure-for-the-send%28%29-method) (emphasis added):

> If the response is an HTTP redirect:
>
> > If the origin of the URL conveyed by the Location header is same origin
> >     with the XMLHttpRequest origin and the
> >     redirect does not violate infinite
> >     loop precautions, **transparently
> >     follow the redirect** while observing
> >     the same-origin request event rules.

They were [considering](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-XMLHttpRequest-20080415/#notcovered) it for a future release:

> This specification does not include
>   the following features which are being
>   considered for a future version of
>   this specification:
>
> - Property to disable following redirects;

but the [latest](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/) specification no longer mentions this.

Comment: What is ridiculous is when the transparent redirect involves overwriting some HTTP headers that were set in the original request.  Specifically, if the "Accept" header was set to a specific content-type, Firefox fails to include this header when following the redirect (which makes it a tad more difficult to develop fully REST-based web services that use this header... grumble).

Comment: Some more searching brought me this rather old bug report: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=401564

Comment: Agree, totally rediculus design flaw.

Comment: It is now possible by using Fetch API. So this answer is no longer valid.

Answer (score 40):

The new [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) supports different modes of redirect handling: `follow`, `error`, and `manual`, but I can't find a way to view the new URL or the status code when the redirection has been canceled. You just can stop the redirection itself, and then it looks like an error (empty response). If that's all you need, you are good to go. <strike>Also you should be aware that the requests made via this API are not cancelable [yet](https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/27).</strike> *They [are](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46785332) now.*

As for XMLHttpRequest, you can `HEAD` the server and inspect whether the URL has changed:

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open('HEAD', '/the/url');
http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
        console.log(this.responseURL);
    }
};
http.send();
```

You won't get the status code, but will find the new URL without downloading the whole page from it.

Comment: Sometimes using `OPTIONS` may be a better choice, anyway only works for non general purpose, etc. administrator had configured redirect the whole site / schema, such as HTTP -> HTTPS

Comment: You cannot find a way because there is no way to find out what the destination URL is. This is for security reasons. See:
https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#atomic-http-redirect-handling

Answer (score 12):

No you there isn't any place in the API exposed by XMLHttpRequest that allows you to override its default behaviour of following a 301 or 302 automatically.

If the client is running IE on windows then you can use WinHTTP instead to set an option to prevent that behaviour but thats a very limiting solution.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `responseURL` property to get the redirect destination or check whether the response was ultimately fetched from a location you accept. 

This of course means the result is fetched anyway, but at least you can get the necessary info about the redirect destination and for example detect conditions when you would like to discard the response.

Comment: Does not work in IE https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseURL

Answer (score 4):

I extended user's answer to include an `abort()` call. It seems like this prevents the server from sending too much data when all you want is the redirect url.

```js
var url = 'the url'
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open('GET', url);
http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
        console.log(this.responseURL)
        this.abort() // This seems to stop the response
    }
}
http.send()
```

In real life I wrapped the above code in a promise, but it made the code hard to read.

Also, I don't understand why getting the redirect url needs to be this difficult, but that is a question for another time and place.

Comment: I tried jquery, fetch, and finally XHR,  only xhr worked and your code works for POST request as well. Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

If the server sends a redirect using status code `307` (Temporary Redirect), this can work (at least in Chrome).

```js
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://endpoint-that-can-return-redirect", true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.HEADERS_RECEIVED) {
        // server responded with headers first
        // 'this.response' is still 'null' here,
        // but 'this.status' is '200', not '307' as could be expected
        let redirect_location = this.responseURL;
        // cancel the request
        this.abort();
        doSomethingWithRedirectLocation(redirect_location);
    }
};
xhr.onload = function() {
    if (this.status == 200) {
        // server sends actual data, not a redirect
        let data = this.response; // or 'this.reponseText'
    }
};
xhr.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

As according to [XMLHttpRequest Living Standard — Last Updated 19 February 2024](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#infrastructure-for-the-send%28%29-method)

is written:

> headers received: All redirects (if any) have been followed and all
> headers of a response have been received.

that means "all redirections is made transparently, and it is no way to control this flow programically".

BUT

You can use fetch() ([Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)). It has build in "[manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch#manual)" option to controll redirections.

Please notice, that "manual" option does NOT controll the state of connection ! So there is no "done" or "error" answer. You need to add into you server application proper handlers.

BUT - assuming, that you just want to cancel redirected connection, it is no need to expect any answer from server because the connection it self will be cancelled, so there wont be any answer at all.

In practise it goes like this:

```
fetch(url, {
    redirect: 'manual',
    method: "POST",
    body: data
}).then((res) => {
    // if(res.ok){  <--- this is the main misunderstanding of "manual" option, that programmers await for "ok". But it will never come in "manual" option !
        you can continue programm after cancelling redirected connection ...
    // }
}).catch((error) => {
    this error handler handles errors of first from redirection chain connection
}
```

Notice, that **first** connction from redirections chains **will** be done and finished (!) This is obvious because only after this first connection will the fetch() mechanism aware that redirection is planned to be established.

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible to handle redirect or 302 status at client side as answered in other comments. However you can prevent redirection. To do that you can set request header "X-Requested-With" with "XMLHttpRequest"
xhttp.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
This should be done after open but before send. Example below

```
let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
   if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
         reqObj.success(JSON.parse(this.responseText))
   } else if (this.status != 200) {
         reqObj.error(this.statusText)
   }
};
xhttp.open(reqObj.type, reqObj.url, reqObj.async);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
xhttp.send();
```

Comment: This is the only working solution! Thank you!

Comment: This will not work. `status` is 0 by design and headers are always empty. This is for security reasons. See:
https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#atomic-http-redirect-handling