# How to get response url in XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, response

There is a page (url), I request it by XMLHttpRequest, but I'm not getting response from requested url, It's directing request to another page,

requesting --- >  **page.php** 
getting reponse from > **directedpage.php**

and the question is how can I get response url? (directedpage.php in example)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The final URL (after following all redirects) is available in the [`responseURL` attribute](http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-responseurl-attribute) of a `XMLHttpRequest` instance.
This feature is new and only supported in Firefox 32 <sup>stable in September 2014 [[ref]](https://wiki.mozilla.org/RapidRelease/Calendar)</sup> and Chrome 37.0.2031.0 <sup>stable in August 2014 [[ref]](http://www.chromium.org/developers/calendar)</sup> (and probably also Opera 24). `responseURL` is not (yet) supported in IE 11 or Safari 7 and older browsers. For these browsers, the previous answer is still true:

> `XMLHttpRequest` automatically follows redirects, without saving the served URLs in a property. The `Location` header can neither be retrieved through the `.getResponseHeader()`.

References:

- https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/msg/blink-dev/AU6pAiYZ8J4/ec5jgoEDsF0J
- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=998076

Comment: OK, but, does someone know why ? Security ? Which attack should be available with the response url ? (Giving response url only if response url is in the same origin than the original url)

Comment: @JulienPalard [The specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#infrastructure-for-the-send()-method) demands that redirects have to be followed transparently.

Comment: @RobW : I don’t understand, if I have this`A=302—B=302—>C=302—>A=200`. What responseURL will return ? The ᴜʀʟ of C or A ?

Comment: @user2284570 The URL of the last A.

Comment: @RobW : And in the case of a circled redirect ?

Comment: @user2284570 It will probably be `null`, because the browser will detect the redirect loop and abort the request.

Comment: Is it impossible to get `responseURL` for blocked CORS requests?

Comment: @traxium It is not possible to get `responseURL` for blocked cross-origin requests. If the server did not respond with the expected CORS response headers. then the browser has to assume that the server is not willing to volunteer sensitive information and therefore it will not leak the redirection target to the script.