# Detecting a redirect in ajax request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, http

I want to use jQuery to GET a URL and explicitly check if it responded with a 302 redirect, but *not* follow the redirect.

jQuery's `$.ajax` appears to always follow redirects.  How can I prevent this, and see the redirect without following it?

There are various questions with titles like "jquery ajax redirect" but they all appear to involve accomplishing some other goal, rather than just directly checking the status that a server gives.

Comment: In my particular case, I expect JSON response on _success_ and HTML response if there was a redirect to a login page. I ended up checking if `xhr.getResponseHeader("content-type")` begins with `text/html` and contains a keyword such as "login" and show a "your session has timed out" if necessary. This of course is not really an answer but a workaround.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

The AJAX request never has the opportunity to NOT follow the redirect (i.e., it must follow the redirect). More information can be found in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2573589/965648

Answer (score 49):

Welcome to the future!

Right now we have a "responseURL" property from xhr object. YAY!

See [How to get response url in XMLHttpRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056277/how-to-get-response-url-in-xmlhttprequest)

However, jQuery (at least 1.7.1) doesn't give an access to XMLHttpRequest object directly.
You can use something like this:

```
var xhr;
var _orgAjax = jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr;
jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr = function () {
  xhr = _orgAjax();
  return xhr;
};

jQuery.ajax('http://test.com', {
  success: function(responseText) {
    console.log('responseURL:', xhr.responseURL, 'responseText:', responseText);
  }
});
```

It's not a clean solution and i suppose jQuery team will make something for responseURL in the future releases.

**TIP**: just compare original URL with responseUrl. If it's equal then no redirect was given. If it's "undefined" then responseUrl is probably not supported. However as Nick Garvey said, AJAX request never has the opportunity to NOT follow the redirect but you may resolve a number of tasks by using **responseUrl** property.

Comment: To add some more resources on this attribute --  [MDN page on XHR.responseURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseURL) -- general support seems to be waiting on MSIE, which only added it in Edge/14.

Comment: Thanks ! Very usefull

Comment: I found that this code actually makes $.ajax({url: 'someurl', xhrFields:{withCredentials:true}}) throw an error in Internet Explorer because the function _orgAjax depends upon the 'this' variable resolving to the $.ajaxSettings object.  When it doesn't, jQuery creates an ActiveX IXMLHTTPRequest object instead of an XMLHttpRequest object, which doesn't support the withCredentials property.  I fixed this by calling xhr = _orgAjax.call($.ajaxSettings); instead of xhr = _orgAjax();  I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 14):

While the other folks who answered this question are (sadly) correct that this information is hidden from us by the browser, I thought I'd post a workaround I came up with:

I configured my server app to set a custom response header (`X-Response-Url`) containing the url that was requested. Whenever my ajax code receives a response, it checks if `xhr.getResponseHeader("x-response-url")` is defined, in which case it compares it to the url that it originally requested via `$.ajax()`. If the strings differ, I know there was a redirect, and additionally, what url we actually arrived at.

This does have the drawback of requiring some server-side help, and also may break down if the url gets munged (due to quoting/encoding issues etc) during the round trip... but for 99% of cases, this seems to get the job done.

---

On the server side, my specific case was a python application using the Pyramid web framework, and I used the following snippet:

```
import pyramid.events

@pyramid.events.subscriber(pyramid.events.NewResponse)
def set_response_header(event):
    request = event.request
    if request.is_xhr:
        event.response.headers['X-Response-URL'] = request.url
```

Comment: It is true indeed that there is no way to know if there is a redirect without taking it; but maybe comparing the expected header URL with the redirected one can be a workaround for me at this moment. Thanks for the idea

Answer (score 7):

You can now use [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)/ It returns `redirected: *boolean*`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the accepted answer AJAX request never has the opportunity to NOT follow the redirect. But I found a workaround that might be helpful for someone.

```
$.ajax("ajax_link_here", {
    data: {},
    contentType: 'application/json',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {

        // originally this request should return status 200 content type "application/json"
        // ajax requests can not capture status 302 redirect response as browser handles the 302 request automatically
        // so detecting the content type "text/html" which means the request has already redirected

        if (xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Type").includes('text/html')) {
            // if this section is reached, it means the request has received a 302 redirect response
        }

    }
});
```