# xmlhttp.status get 200 status code for redirection

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, tornado

send ajax to tornado server for redirection and get 200 status code.
client side

```
 $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: url,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    data: data,
                    complete: function (xmlHttp, textStatus) {
                        alert(xmlHttp.status.toString());
                        alert(textStatus);
                        if (xmlHttp.status.toString()[0] == '3') {
                            top.location.href = xmlHttp.getResponseHeader('Location');
                            alert(top.location.href)
                        }
                    }
                });
```

server side

```
class Login(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
    print "post"
    print self.request.body
    self.redirect("/")
```

on chrome  browser F12 network tag

```
login            post 302 ...
10.xxx.xxx.xxx   get  304 ...
```

why the alert function display 200 status code?
Thanks

Comment: jQuery "automatically" follow redirects when doing AJAX requests, so you don't get to "see" the redirect on the client. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9177252/detecting-a-redirect-in-jquery-ajax

Comment: if that, what is the best way to implement my ideal?  I want to redirect to another page if server send me a redirection code

Comment: So you want to redirect to a page *different* from that that the server redirects you to?