# Session attribute is lost after invoking a client-side redirect

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, session

Previously, the servlet uses `response.sendRedirect("pages/my_page.jsp?foo=bar");` without problem. Session attributes can be retrieved in the subsequent pages being redirected to.

Currently, I am changing the way to send requests. Originally, the Javascript uses `myForm.submit();`, but I have now changed it to `jQuery.ajax("my_page.jsp?foo=bar", {...});`. Then, the servlet includes a URL in the JSON response instead of `response.sendRedirect()`, and in the `success` function, I use `window.location.replace(url);` to navigate to the new page. However, the saved session attributes cannot be fetched in subsequent pages.

I have compared the session IDs by inserting `<%= session.getId() %>` in my JSP pages. They are the same. The issue here is `session.getAttribute("myAttribute_1")` returns `null` in the page redirected to.

I am not sure if this matters, but I am in fact doing this task with more than 1 JSP pages:

```
A.jsp --- (redirect) ---> B.jsp --- (redirect) ---> C.jsp
```

In this case, how can I get the saved session attributes in `C.jsp`?

---

### Edit

Below is the code snippet I use to save session attribute.

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);

    response.setContentType("application/json");

    CustomObject customObject = new CustomObject();
    // ...
    session.setAttribute("myAttribute_1", customObject);

    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
    JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();

    json.addProperty("url", "next_page.jsp?foo=bar");
    writer.println(gson.toJson(json));
    writer.close();
}
```

Below is the code snippet for redirecting.

```
function redirectHandler(data, currentUrl) {
    if (data && data.hasOwnProperty('url')) {
        var redirectUrl = data.url;
        jQuery.get(redirectUrl).done(function(response) {
            redirectHandler(response, redirectUrl);
        });
    } else {
        window.location.replace(currentUrl);
    }
}

function sendFormData(method, url, form) {
    jQuery.ajax(url, {
        'method': method,
        'data': parseData(jQuery(form).serializeArray()),
        'success': function(data) {
            redirectHandler(data, window.location.href);
        }
    });
}
```

---

### Result

I have reverted back to using `response.sendRedirect("pages/my_page.jsp?foo=bar")` in my servlet.

On the client side, `jQuery.ajax()` is removed and the function `sendFormData()` is updated as follows.

```
function sendFormData(form) {
    var data = parseData(jQuery(form).serializeArray());
    var f = document.createElement('form');

    for (var key in data) {
        jQuery('<input>').attr({
            'type': 'hidden',
            'name': key,
            'value': data[key]
        }).appendTo(f);
    }

    f.setAttribute('method', form.getAttribute('method'));
    f.setAttribute('action', form.getAttribute('action'));
    f.submit();
}
```

Whenever I want to submit a form, a `click` event handler is attached. It will call `sendFormData(myOriginalForm);` rather than `myOriginalForm.submit();` as I need to customize the data to be sent.

Only by applying these simple changes, everything works again.

Still, I am looking for an explanation on this weird behavior.

Comment: can you please post code where you actually saved Attribute into session with attribute named - "myAttribute_1" ?

Comment: @Mr.VishalJGajera There you are.

Comment: if possible then post whole code from where to where you are calling ? i am think that you did some little bit mistake, but can not sure so that code needed.

Comment: @Mr.VishalJGajera Code updated.

Comment: Okay, code looks fine. Also another doubt, can you show me flow from where to where gone into 1-line. like, a.jsp  ---> Servlet.java ---> newjsp.jsp, Also check as per you thinking flow goes perfectly likewise, also debug code for checking flow as per your wish.

Comment: @Mr.VishalJGajera I have included the JS code for redirecting pages.

Comment: upload whole code at some Repo. will provide you whole solution.Because i can not exactly identify. so if possible then do it.

Comment: @Mr.VishalJGajera Nevermind then. It is something private so I cannot upload everything.

Comment: Most likely it is duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870371/why-is-jquerys-ajax-method-not-sending-my-session-cookie

Comment: @sibnick But I am redirecting to pages in the same domain...

Comment: But it is important that script (jquery) domain should be from your server.

Comment: @sibnick Yes, the JSP pages, Javascript files, and Java servlet are all on the same server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## On the server side

HTTP requests are stateless and the sessions are laid on top of HTTP by different means like

- **URL rewriting** (e.g. server starts new session and returns its ID to the client, then client appends session id to all subsequent requests `http://host:port/path;session_id=12345`)
- **cookies** (e.g upon session creation server responds with a cookie encoding  session ID, and on the server side you expect that cookie to correlate each request with existing session).

It is the client's responsibility to ensure that they participate in the session by the means expected by the server. When the server is implemented using Java Servlet API it is either **jsessionid** cookie or the query parameter with the same name appended to the URL, which identifies the session id.

If the client does not support cookies, using Java Servlet API you will have to redirect to
   a URL created by `HttpServletResponse.encodeRedirectURL(String url)`.

In order to redirect from a servlet use `HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect(String url);`.

Responding form the server with standard for HTTP redirects will simplify your design. **Jquery** does implement these standards and therfore will honour **HTTP 301** and **302** responses from the server as [ilustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9177252/detecting-a-redirect-in-jquery-ajax) so no redirect logic on the client side should be needed.

---

### On the client side

Your client is **jquery** and its ajax implementation will respect and replay the cookies set for any given domain, when subsequent request will be made to the same domain.

If you are redirecting to a different domain, for **jquery** to work with **CORS** sessions, please add `xhrFields` to your request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: a_cross_domain_url,
    xhrFields: {
      withCredentials: true
    }
});
```

as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870371/why-is-jquerys-ajax-method-not-sending-my-session-cookie)

Comment: If the domain is omitted from the URL in my ajax call, does it count as a cross domain request?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried different forms of Javascript redirects?

Recommended approach is:

```
window.location.href=currentUrl;
```

According to this [article](http://rricketts.com/javascript-window-location-redirects-assigns-replace-and-more/), using `window.location.replace` will replace the current session.

Comment: Could you not redirect and pass reference information as well, so you can then create the new session once the redirect is on the new address?

Comment: @StevenScott I could see the JSESSIONID being sent with ajax, only several attributes in the original session were lost. Creating new session is not a viable solution in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and [tore my hair out looking for the best solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70343060/12654533). Try putting `sessionCookiePath="/"` attribute into your context.xml root node:

`<Context ... sessionCookiePath="/" > ... </Context>`

This will set the path of your session cookie to the root of your app so that it will be passed on redirect. This simple fix worked for me.

Many people will suggest URL encoding or storing the session ID in another cookie, but based on my understanding this is the best solution if it works for you. (Session cookies are [considered strictly necessary](https://www.cookieyes.com/session-cookies/), so using them as intended is probably best practice.)