# Load entire page with redirect response in Ajax POST request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, redirect

My POST request handler can either return content that I load into a div or the browser is redirected.  When I use jQuery's `.post()`, in the case of a redirect, instead of the entire page redirecting, the content returned from the redirect is loaded into the div:

```
var request = $.post('/my-post-url/');

request.done(function(response) {
  $('#my-div').empty();
  $('#my-div').append(response); // In case of redirect, response has new page's contents
});
```

To get around this, I use the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26750780/2233706):

```
request.done(function(response) {
  if(xhr.responseURL != window.location.href.match(/(^[^#]*)/)[0])
  {
    location.href = xhr.responseURL;
    return;
  }

  $('#my-div').empty();
  $('#my-div').append(response);
});
```

This works fine, but I end up doing two `GET` requests for the same content: the first one is done automatically by the time I get inside the `done` handler, and the second is when I set `location.href`.  Is there a way to either prevent this extra GET request and/or redirect the ENTIRE page on a redirect?

Comment: No. There is not

Comment: Doesn't seem to be possible. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228225/prevent-redirection-of-xmlhttprequest

Comment: Instead of returning plain HTML or a redirect, return a JSON object that indicates whether the client should redirect or display the HTML. `{ type: "html", data: "content to display" }` or `{type: "redirect", data: "URL to redirect to" }`

Comment: Barmar that was what I wanted to do next but wanted to see if this was possible.