# preventDefault() not working on a form request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have the following form which process a password recovery script requested by the user.

```
<form class="forget-form" id="forget-form" action="datacenter/functions/passwordRecovery.php" method="POST">
    <h3 class="font-green">Esqueceu sua senha?</h3>
    <p> Digite seu e-mail abaixo para receber o procedimento para uma nova senha.</p>
    <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom:0px">
        <input class="form-control placeholder-no-fix" type="email" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Seu e-mail" name="email" id="email" required/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-actions">
        <button type="button" id="back-btn" class="btn red btn-outline uppercase"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-left"></i> voltar</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success uppercase pull-right uppercase"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> enviar</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

For that, I'm using ajax to keep the user on the same screen without any redirect.

```
$("#forget-form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    if(isEmail(email) == true){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'datacenter/functions/passwordRecovery.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: new FormData(this),
            async: true,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(error, errorThrown, errorShowcase){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    } else {
        console.log('this is not an email');
    }
});
```

The file `passwordRecovery.php` only `echo "success";` to log on the console, just to check if it really worked, and it is working, but too fast, it logs on the console and after that redirects me to `passwordRecovery.php`, not preventing the default action of the form.

Have you ever faced that?

Comment: try `return false` at the end of your submit callback

Comment: already did that, but it didnt work. also tried to run the submit in $(function(){});, it keeps redirecting me

Comment: Could you post a [mcve]? I can't reproduce the problem

Comment: Any errors in your developer console? Do you have any other elements with the same ID? What happens if you do `console.log(document.querySelectorAll("#forget-form").length);` ?

Comment: What other errors do you have in your console?

Comment: no errors @CrazyTrain, and it returns 1 doing that

Comment: no errors @Top-Bot

Comment: How about if you remove all code from the `submit` handler, except for the `e.preventDefault()`. Does it still fail to prevent the submission?

Comment: it is funny because if i type a not valid e-mail, it prevents my form to process and log `this is not an email`, but if it is a valid e-mail, it redirects

Comment: Do you have something in the php file causing the redirect?

Comment: can you try adding e.preventDefault() inside your success ajax function?

Comment: This may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9177252/detecting-a-redirect-in-jquery-ajax (Actually, not sure if it's relevant. I didn't think XHR could redirect the viewed page.)

Comment: just an `echo` @Pete

Comment: If you remove that contentType option, does it make a difference - I once I used that contentType and as the page I was loading was not the type it expected, it redirected to the page instead of ajaxing it

Comment: In your browser console, go to settings and ensure you have "preserve log" selected.  It could be that you have a script error which is being cleared because you are POSTing.

Comment: I don't believe `false` is a proper `contentType` parameter...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$('#forget-form').submit(function () {
//your code
return false;
});
```