# How to access HTTP response url of websites using javascript

Tags: javascript, python, url, response

Please edit the question if the title is not informative enough.

I am working with a website that uses javascript. This is an exemplary [url](https://www.punters.com.au/form-guide/Mildura_58368/Trentham-Estate-Maiden-Plate_349767/#OddsComparison). 
The page sends a request to a web server and loads the response data back. I am seeking for the url of that response.

Typically we can investiage element with Firebug and under the Network tab there is a list of response urls but not this time. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think that [responseURL](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-responseurl-attribute) is what you want, it will be available as a request property after the call is over.

Just be aware its non standard and does not exist on IE and Safari, as well as old Mozilla/Chrome browsers (v30/35- I guess)

You cant get more informations [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056277/how-to-get-response-url-in-xmlhttprequest).