# YQL, is it possible to get response url (to get 'https://www.yahoo.com' given only 'yahoo.com')?

Tags: javascript, yql

Is there a way to get a "full" URL out of a "short" URL using YQL. E.g. is there a table or something else to get 'https://www.amazon.com/' knowing only 'amazon.com' (and not knowing whether it's 'http' or 'https', or whether it's prefixed by 'www.' or not)?

In XMLHttpRequest we can get response URL in `xhr.responseURL` ([How to get response url in XMLHttpRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056277/how-to-get-response-url-in-xmlhttprequest)) but it doesn't work for cross-origin requests.

Comment: no...you need an absolute url

Comment: I don't need an absolute url in `SELECT * FROM html WHERE url='yahoo.com'`