# HBBTV 1.1.1 xmlhttprequest.responseURL

Tags: javascript, ajax, hbbtv

i need get xmlhttprequest.responseURL for hbbtv 1.1.1 (version browser Opera 12.11) in vaniliaJS. Is there somebody, who know the answer?

Comment: There is no such concept as response URL. This may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056277/how-to-get-response-url-in-xmlhttprequest

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with that version of the HbbTV standard, but if supported by a compliant device the [documentaiton on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseURL) should be correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the response in the `XMLHttpRequest()` then the answer is:

```
try{
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       //do something here if you want
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", URL, true); //true for synchronous and false for asynchronous
    xhttp.send();  
} catch (error){
//do something with the error
}
```