# In Chrome, how many redirects are "too many"?

Tags: google-chrome, webkit

Often, when a script has a redirect loop we get an error in Google Chrome that says

> Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects.

How many redirects are too many?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Google Chrome 17.0.963.56 allows a maximum of 20 redirects, as tested with this PHP script:

```
<?php
    $redirect = (isset($_GET['redirect'])) ? $_GET['redirect'] : 0;
    header("Location: redirects.php?redirect=" . ($redirect + 1));
?>
```

Chrome aborts with error `310` when trying to open `redirects.php?redirect=21`, which means that the first `20` redirects were successful.

Comment: For people inexperienced with PHP, is there a quick & easy way to run this script that you could share?

Comment: @AdamS If PHP is installed and in your path, you can use the [built-in web server](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php). Save this script as `redirects.php` in your working directory, run `php -S localhost:8080`, and then navigate to http://localhost:8080/redirects.php with your browser of choice.

Answer (score 59):

Tested on Win 7 64bit

- **Chrome 64bit** `Version: 49`  <kbd>↷</kbd> `105.0.5195.127 (Official Build)`, **(19*X)** redirects
- **Chrome Canary 64bit**, `Version: 49` <kbd>↷</kbd> `108.0.5337.0  (Official Build)`, **(19*X)** redirects
  `3 retries sum up to 57 redirects`
- **Firefox 32-bit** `version: 43`  <kbd>↷</kbd> `105.0.1`, **20** redirects
- **Firefox 64-bit** `version: 43`  <kbd>↷</kbd> `105.0.1`, **20** redirects

  - **Firefox 64-bit** `67.0.4`, ***endless loop!***
- **Opera** `version: 28`, <kbd>↷</kbd> `90.0.4480.84` **(19*3)** redirects
- **Safari** `version: 5.1.7`, **16** redirects
- **IE** `version: 8`  **11** redirects *via [webpagetest.org](http://www.webpagetest.org)*
- **IE** `version: 9`  **121** redirects *via [webpagetest.org](http://www.webpagetest.org)*
- **IE** `version: 10` **121** redirects *via [webpagetest.org](http://www.webpagetest.org)*
- **IE** `version: 11.48.17134.0` **110** redirects
- **Microsoft Edge** `version: 42.17134.1.0` **20** redirects
- **Microsoft Edge** `version: 105.0.1343.53` **(19 * X)**
  redirects
  `5 retries sum up to 95 redirects`
- **Google Nexus 5, Samsung Galaxy S4 ⇄ S9, Galaxy Tab 4**, **19** redirects

Comment: Surely there's an extra digit in those IE numbers!

Comment: @BrunoBronosky, nope, 110 and 120 are correct.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome and Firefox out of the box is 20, Internet Explorer is 10, I couldn't tell you on Opera or Safari

Comment: *Internet Explorer is 10.* What version? Because I've tested with IE 9 and the maximum was `110`.

Comment: I would have said IE9 intially, but its possible we experienced it with IE8. I can't imagine that Microsoft would have changed the limit to 110 in IE9 when other browsers aren't configured even close to that. Wonder if you've had something modify the registry setting that affects redirects

Comment: As far as I know, the default setting can be modified only in `[HKCU|HKLM]\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\MaxHttpRedirects`. I checked and neither value does exist.

Comment: interesting... I cannot find any of the documentation that we found on it before, but a couple years ago we were having issues with some redirects in a authentication module that we had written and it would work fine in FF/Chrome, but would bomb out in IE everytime. We found that on certain occasions, it was doing 12-13 redirects and IE was crapping out

Comment: I couldn't find another machine with IE 9, but I discovered [WebPagetest.org](http://www.webpagetest.org). The results are fairly strange: Only `10` redirects for IE 7 and 8, but `110` for IE 9 and `102` for IE 6. Also, IE 9 refreshes after every 10th redirect and IE 6 refreshes after the 100th.

Comment: Do you have an external url that you are using to test? I have a couple VM's that I've used in the past for testing IE compatibility with default installs of each version of IE. I'd like to see the results from a real browser if you don't mind, out of pure curiosity

Comment: Cool, I'll fire up my VM's this evening and post back the results that I find as well.

Comment: Is there anyway to ignore this? Or clear the redirect loop count?