# How to redirect to iOS when custom URI Scheme not supported by provider

Tags: ios, rest, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to use a REST API for my iOS application, however, I've noticed that many sites won't allow a app-specific URL scheme for the redirect URI. In one case, only an `https://...` URL is allowed.

Is there a way to redirect back to an iOS app in these cases?

Answer (score 1):

Although there's a thing as [too many redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9384474/in-chrome-how-many-redirects-are-too-many), just one more won't probably reach the limit. You can have your own HTTPS endpoint that redirects the request again to your app-specific URL scheme.

If you don't want to host it yourself you can do something really simple as creating a [webtask](https://webtask.io) that just redirects the received request and parameters back to your app.

This example in the [documentation](https://webtask.io/docs/model) shows how to control the HTTP response within a webtask:

```
module.exports = function (context, req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html '});
    res.end('<h1>Hello, world!</h1>');
}
```

There's of course the need to review it from a security perspective in order to ensure you don't do something stupid, but that's always the case, and in theory this should be feasible.

Comment: I've looked at this solution, but haven't been able to figure out how to use it to accomplish what I need.