# How to output content and redirect using ajax and jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, redirect

I am building a registration form with jquery which should handle the request via Ajax.
My code:

```
$.ajax( 
{ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: "http://www.example.com/register.php", 
    data: $("#register-form").serialize(),
    cache: false,
    success: function(message)
    {   
                    $("#reg_notification").html(message).fadeIn(400);               
    }           
});
```

Now the register.php should either output an error if for example the email address is not valid and this will be put into the div reg_notification. If no error is made, then the user should be redirected to a "welcome page". But it is important that this page is not allways static, so in other words, I can not use a `location.href` in the jquery code but want to use

```
header("Location: http://www.example.com")
```

in PHP. The problem is that the user wont be redirected but the content of `www.example.com` will be put inside the div reg_notification.

I found a similar problem here: [How to manage a redirect request after a jQuery Ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call) but the difference is that there they are using json which I can not use due to my server and they are also redirecting inside the javascript and not in the php file.

Comment: You can't redirect in the PHP file and expect the browser to redirect also.

You could replace the entire page with the result from the request.

Comment: Do you have an example of a site that does what you're asking?

Comment: @phpheini Sure, see the question you linked.

Comment: @AdrianLynch Yeah, for example https://twitter.com/signup.
At least thats how I want it to work, but Im not sure what method they are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Impossible with header redirection.

Use something like that:

```
...
success: function(message)
{   
     $("#reg_notification").html(message)
          .fadeIn(400, function() {window.location = "url"});
}
```

or

```
success: function(response)
{   
     if (response.success) {
          $("#reg_notification").html(response.message)
               .fadeIn(400, function() {window.location = response.redirectTo; } );
     } else {
          // somethings else
     }
}
```

in php:

```
header("Content-type: application/json");
echo json_encode(array(
    "success" => true,
    "message" => "some message",
    "redirectTo" => "my url"
));
```

**UPDATE**
header redirect impossible because XMLHttpRequest transparently follows to redirect url for get result. See [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820663/is-it-possible-for-xhr-head-requests-to-not-follow-redirects-301-302)

Comment: Your first example would allways redirect me even if an error has occured. In the second example, how would I tell the script where to redirect to?

Comment: I now have json on my server so I tried this and I dont get why it doesnt work: `$.ajax( 
 { 
  type: "POST", 
  url: "http://www.example.com/register.php", 
  data: $("#register-form").serialize(),
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data, textStatus) {
   if (data.redirect) {
    window.location.replace(data.redirect);
   }
   else {
    $("#signin_message").replaceWith(data.form);
   }
     }   
 });`
And then in the php: `header("Content-type: application/json");
echo json_encode(array(
    "success" => true,
    "form" => "some message",
    "redirect" => "http://www.example.com"
));`

Comment: first step add console.log(data); and check result.. if data valid json object then try window.location = data.redirect...