# Ajax, redirect and DELETE

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, http, laravel

To honor Laravels conventions, I have want to my users issue DELETE requests, when using destroy routes.

To avoid setting up tedious forms on every delete link, I have deviced this piece of jQuery code which turn any `a`tags with a `method="delete"` attribute into a DELETE request:

```
$(function() {
  $("a[method='delete']").on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    target = this.getAttribute('href')
    request = new XMLHttpRequest()
    request.open('delete', target, false);
    request.send();
  });
});
```

This code almost does the job. However, when my controllers process the DELETE request in a destroy method, they should redirect the user. For instance, if he destroys a resource he should be redirected to resource index.

I am trying to find a clean way of doing that without responding with a special JSON body, but just using a standard `303` redirect.

Any idea on how to go about that?

Comment: See: [React to 303 status code in jquery ( Prevent from redirecting).](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16337697/react-to-303-status-code-in-jquery-prevent-from-redirecting) Short answer: you can't capture 303 responses in jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a fan of using Javascript to do this. Instead I use a `Form` macro to insert delete buttons for my RESTful resources. (I'm assuming you have an alias for the destroy method, or using Laravel's `Route::resource()` without prefixes, otherwise adjust accordingly.)

```
Form::macro('delete', function($resource, $id) {

    $form_parameters = array(
        'method' => "DELETE",
        'url'    => URL::route("$resource.destroy", $id),
    );

    return Form::open($form_parameters)
            . Form::submit('Delete')
            . Form::close();
});
```

Then, with blade templates I could just write something like this:

```
{{ Form::delete('post', 1) }}
```

Finally, do your 303 redirects normally inside the destroy method of your hypothetical `post` controller.

```
return Redirect::to(URL::route('post.index'), 303);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a viable solution, that makes the JavaScript function a bit dirtier, but keeps the rest of HTML clean. It works by creating a dummy form with a post request and a hidden method attribute and submitting it, thereby getting the request processed and the user redirected.

Keep in mind that you have to append the form to the DOM before submitting it, otherwise some browsers will ignore the form submission.

```
$(function() {
  $("a[method='delete']").on('click', function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    target = this.getAttribute('href')

    form_string = "<form method=\"POST\" action=\"" + target + "\" accept-charset=\"UTF-8\"><input name=\"_method\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"DELETE\"></form>"

    form = $(form_string)
    form.appendTo('body');
    form.submit();
  });
});
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking of as a possible workaround only I would use `form[0].submit()` and I would make the code such that submission is not `CSRF`-rejected.