# What error is ajax Status Code:303

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, joomla

I have a problem. I need your help. When I press on the button, which must work through the ajax, in the network I see 303 see other, which is the problem?how can you help me? Thanks in advance

```
var data = {
                                    action:"video_gallery_ajax",
                                    task:'load_images_lightbox',
                                    page:pagenum,
                                    perpage:perpage,
                                    galleryid:galleryid,
                                    thumbtext:thumbtext,
                                    pID:pID,
                                    likeStyle:likeStyle,
                                    ratingCount:ratingCount
                            }

   jQuery.post('components/com_gallery/ajax_url.php',data,function(response){
                                                                if(response.success){
```

}
}

Comment: show us your ajax code and server side code also

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16337697/react-to-303-status-code-in-jquery-prevent-from-redirecting)

Comment: How about your code snippet?

Answer (score 2):

A `303 See Other` message is an HTTP response status code indicating that the requested resource can be found at another URI (address) by using the GET HTTP method. The `303 See Other` code is typically provided in response to a POST, PUT, or DELETE HTTP method request, which indicates to the client that the server successfully received the data associated with the request, and the client should send a new GET request to the new URI it was provided by the server. See [HTTP response status codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status)

Answer (score 0):

The server is saying that it does not have "a representation of the requested resource" at the given URL. The server will supply a suggested alternative in a location header.

In short: it is a redirect.

It could be that it is trying to redirect you to a secure URL. Try using HTTPS instead.