# Catch "302 Found" when using GWT RequestBuilder

Tags: http, gwt, http-status-code-302

I have a service that responses HTTP Status Code `302 Found`. When calling it with `RequestBuilder.send()` I get redirected automatically, so that the final URL is not equal to the URL initially set for the RequestBuilder.

I need at least the URL the service wants to forward me, in other words the `Location` header of the first response.

Is it possible to prevent the request from being forwarded? Or can I examine the URL with the final Response?

Answer (score 3):

Probably not. RequestBuilder is implemented as XMLHttpRequest, which does not give any feedback on redirects.

Take a look at [Prevent redirection of Xmlhttprequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228225/prevent-redirection-of-xmlhttprequest) for details.