# get AJAX redirect URL in iOS 4 +

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I'm doing an ajax call to a URL that redirects. I can use the getAllResponseHeaders() but there is no location in the response.

Any ideas how to get the URL of the final location? I'm restricted to javascript because I'm used webview within iOS.

Comment: Related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228225/prevent-redirection-of-xmlhttprequest

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want stop the redirect.. I just want th final destination's location