# Mootools: How to get redirected if ajax request returns redirect code?

Tags: ajax, redirect, mootools

I need to redirect user if request returns 302 or 303. It seems that there isn't a standard way to do this (odd, I thought it's quite a common task).

I have this code:

```
var request = new Request({
        url: "/some-url/",
        method: 'get',
        evalScripts: true,
        onComplete: function(){
            console.log(this.status);
        }
    });
```

Console prints 0 status but web inspector shows that the status code is 302 Found, so I can't manually check the code and get redirected. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

normally, an ajax request to a 301/302/303 etc will follow the new `location` and re-issue the request as per specification. if you are not seeing a second request, something is wrong, like an infinite loop or similar...

more here: http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/XMLHttpRequest/#infrastructure-for-the-send-method

Comment: There isn't infinite loop in my case, I've checked again. 1) I don't understand why this.status prints 0, and 2) Do you mean there isn't a way to make browser follow the redirect that comes from ajax request?

Comment: no, on the contrary, it's not normal behaviour to prevent the browser from following the redirect... it just happens! here's another post here on the subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228225/prevent-redirection-of-xmlhttprequest - so the question is, what breaks your redirect chain. have a look at your xhr and responses and post them expanded here...

Comment: and the point is, a 301 to same url (for example) would create an infinite loop. this will break the chain as XHR will try to avoid it. also, a redirect to a different protocol (https->http and vice versa) should not work.

Comment: er, your 302 is to another domain. this `does` break the same-origin-policy rules mentioned here: http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/XMLHttpRequest/#same-origin-request-event-rules

Comment: oh, so can we circumvent this by redirecting to the same domain url that would redirect to the needed url then?

Comment: Not directly. It will follow all redirects. You can `proxy` the data and get the response and output it. Check http://enable-cors.org/

Answer (score 2):

I've tryed both cases (302 and 303) and it follows the spec: user agent **automatically** redirects to url, specified in the *Location:* header of response. So, finally console.log(this.status) indeed return `200`, but no worry because redirect is handled by browser automatically (at least in FF and Chrome).

That is the firebug console:

[image: firebug console]

Comment: I see this ([screenshot](http://screenshots.ivanovs.info/28avNM.png)).  0 is the console.log(this.status) result.

Comment: I see in code above you are not actually sending request. `var request = new Request({});` and no .send(); Is it there? :) Just to clear things up show actual code that sends request and maybe that part that generate response headers, or headers themselves.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. [The actual code](http://screenshots.ivanovs.info/JoYZ8t.png).

Comment: code looks no problem. As said in comment to other answer, network activity needs examining. Net tab in developer console.

Comment: just as said in Dimitar Christoff's last comment, problem is cross-domain reference. Reproduced the error.