# How to deal with HTTP 303 in Jquery $.getJSON callback?

Tags: jquery, ajax, redirect, getjson, logout

If my webapp receives a JSON call from a user who has a stale cookie due to inactivity, my webapp's framework will return a 303 attempting to redirect the browser to a login page.

I'd want to capture this in my callback function but it doesn't seem to execute when encountering a redirect. How do I deal with redirects in JQuery ajax calls? I'm just looking to refresh the page if the user attempts to make a JSON call after being logged out as that will redirect the user to the login page by default.

Comment: Possible solution can be found here => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927044/redirect-on-ajax-jquery-call

Comment: @esailija you replied and then removed your answer after my comment?

Comment: please see this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867021/mootools-how-to-get-redirected-if-ajax-request-returns-redirect-code

Answer (score 0):

@esailija's solution worked so they needn't have deleted it:

```
function myfunc(){
    $.getJSON('serverJSONCall',function(data){
        if(data.success){
            // do something interesting
    }).error( function() {
        location.reload();
    });
}
```