# Cancel Fetch Streams

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, fetch

I can't figure out how to cancel a fetch stream. I tried the following code, which didn't cancel the stream.

```
fetch(url).then(function(response) {
 response.body.cancel()
})
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I cancel an HTTP fetch() request?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31061838/how-do-i-cancel-an-http-fetch-request)

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in [this open issue](https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/27), at the time of writing, it's not possible to abort a `fetch` stream.

Take a look at this other answer: [How do I cancel an HTTP fetch() request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31061838/how-do-i-cancel-an-http-fetch-request)

Comment: crbug.com/469154 seems to indicate otherwise.