# Fetch API vs XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, fetch-api

I know that Fetch API uses `Promise`s and both of them allow you to do AJAX requests to a server.

I have read that Fetch API has some extra features, which aren't available in `XMLHttpRequest` (and in the Fetch API polyfill, since it's based on `XHR`).

What extra capabilities does the Fetch API have?

Comment: Though I can't recall on the spot, there are one or two things you can do with XHR you can't with fetch. You say you have read that fetch has extra possibilities, those articles aren't very good if they don't say what they are

Comment: found the two things you can't do with fetch that you can with XHR ... you can't set your own value for request timeout in fetch, nor can you get progress events

Comment: Fetch is just a simplified way of doing things for most types of XMLHttpRequests.  If your use case fits what Fetch does, then use it.  When you get right down to it the XMLHttpRequest API is ugly for what most people use it for.  Fetch was an effort to offer a cleaner way of doing things that doesn't need a library wrapped around XMLHttpRequest to make it palatable.

Comment: It has pure support in browsers ( http://caniuse.com/#search=fetch ), so there is a polifill for it https://github.com/github/fetch, wich is working above xhr

Comment: @jfriend00, that's incorrect, fetch is not a simplified way, but a more low-level way (indeed, XHR is now defined in terms of Fetch: https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-send%28%29-method).

Comment: @Marco - How can you not say that `fetch(url).then(function(data) (...));` is not simpler than using `XMLHttpRequest` to do the same thing?  It may have lots of other features, but geez, it sure is simpler to use for common things.  It IS a cleaned up API.

Comment: Wait, I'm not saying it isn't simpler. I'm saying that your comment was incorrect, because you said "fetch is JUST a simplified way ...", this makes people think, incorrectly, that fetch doesn't have more features than XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: Fetch is not a simplified way of XHR. It's sort of more complicated. You can't even reuse the response text/object without relying on the `.clone()` voodoo that itself is a complicated promise-based method compared to XHR's straightforward approach.

Answer (score 203, accepted):

There are a few things that you can do with fetch and not with XHR:

- You can use the Cache API with the request and response objects;
- You can perform `no-cors` requests, getting a response from a server that doesn't implement CORS. You can't access the response body directly from JavaScript, but you can use it with other APIs (e.g. the Cache API);
- Streaming responses (with XHR the entire response is buffered in memory, with fetch you will be able to access the low-level stream). This isn't available yet in all browsers, but will be soon.

There are a couple of things that you can do with XHR that you can't do yet with fetch, but they're going to be available sooner or later (read the "Future improvements" paragraph here: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/03/this-api-is-so-fetching/):

- Abort a request (this now works in Firefox and Edge, as @sideshowbarker explains in his comment);
- Report progress.

This article https://jakearchibald.com/2015/thats-so-fetch/ contains a more detailed description.

Comment: The spec for the Fetch API now provides for cancellation. Support has so far shipped in Firefox 57 and Edge 16. Demos: https://fetch-abort-demo-edge.glitch.me/, https://mdn.github.io/dom-examples/abort-api/. And there are open Chrome & Webkit feature bugs https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=750599, https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=174980. How-to: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/abortable-fetch,  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortSignal#Examples. And example in the Stack Overflow answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/47250621/441757

Comment: Another difference is that `fetch` requests can't be replayed on Developer Tools.

Comment: And, from my experience, `fetch` can request for files, but XHR can't.

Comment: Reporting in 2021, still no way to track progress for requests (or responses) created with the `fetch` API. `XMLHttpRequest` thus dies a slow agonising death, if at all.

Comment: is there any speed difference in requesting and getting back the request or are they the same in performance ?

Comment: What's a Cache api?

Comment: You can't bypass CORS using `fetch()`.

Answer (score 108):

### fetch

- missing a builtin method to consume documents
- no way to set a timeout [yet](https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/179)
- can't override the content-type response header
- if the content-length response header is present *but not exposed*, the body's total length is unknown during the streaming
- will call the signal's abort handler *even* if the request has been completed
- no upload progress (support for `ReadableStream` instances as request bodies is [yet to come](http://w3c-test.org/fetch/api/basic/request-upload.any.html))
- [doesn't support `--allow-file-access-from-files`](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=810400) (chromium)

### XHR

- there's no way to *not* send cookies (apart from using the [non-standard `mozAnon` flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/XMLHttpRequest#Parameters_(non-standard)) or the `AnonXMLHttpRequest` constructor)
- can't return `FormData` instances
- doesn't have an equivalent to `fetch`'s `no-cors` mode
- always follows redirects

Comment: `fetch` is also missing progress. with XHR you can track progress with the `progress` event

Comment: "can't override the content-type header of the response"... this is just a bad idea to begin with. the 'content-type dictates what is to be returned and the BACKEND SHOULD dictate that to the frontend. IN FACT, content-type should be the 'ONLY HEADER' for type because what is requested, is what should be returned. If you want something different serve from a special subdomain or something so you can handles specific functionality separate. You ar trying to force a 1% rule down 99% of everyones throat.

Comment: @Knu yep and now we are more advanced and we can easily automate a 90% solution and let the freak cases route to different functionality.

Comment: @rzr not exactly, you got `Response#body`.

Comment: Granted, [it doesn't look like `no-cors` is that useful anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43268098/1874170)...

Answer (score 25):

The answers above are good and provide good insights, but I share the same opinion as shared in this [google developers blog entry](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch) in that the main difference (from a practical perspective) is the convenience of the built-in promise returned from `fetch`

Instead of having to write code like this

```
function reqListener() {
    var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
}

function reqError(err) { ... }

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.onload = reqListener;
oReq.onerror = reqError;
oReq.open('get', './api/some.json', true);
oReq.send();
```

we can clean things up and write something a little more concise and readable with promises and modern syntax

```
fetch('./api/some.json')
    .then((response) => {
        response.json().then((data) => { 
            ... 
        });
    })
    .catch((err) => { ... });
```

Comment: @TheOpti You can polyfill basic fetch support into IE 11. You could also just drop IE11 as a supported browser in many projects as in many user bases IE 11 usage is now below 1%.

Comment: I hate IE but I also don't recommend dropping IE support especially when there are polyfills. Millions of people still use IE and other old browsers. Just a few days ago I had to tell a client not to use IE after I saw him using it. Of course if your project is not going to support IE anyway then a polyfill won't help.

Comment: @PHPGuru grr! This pisses me off. **All the latest web technologies are fully unavailable on Internet Explorer.** I wish people would switch to Microsoft Edge, at the very least! And I wish MS would issue an "update" to IE which would disable the browser entirely (or show a nag screen before allowing use) and tell people to switch to another browser.

Comment: I think it's pure marketing on Microsoft's part. If they leave IE on computers that have Edge installed on them, then their hope is that people will think that Edge is a different browser (it's not) and IE's bad reputation will die with IE. The only difference is that Edge is newer than IE. But if you don't make sure you have the latest version of Edge, you might as well be using IE.

Comment: @PHPGuru As someone who worked for a couple of years in a team where we needed IE11 support I can tell you 100% that even the Edge that was based on IE code was very different and better to work with than IE11, which was a nightmare. What's more the new Edge that is based on Chromium, and essentially just a repackaging of Chrome, was released in January 2020, over a year before you wrote this comment. Really weird to me that people still repeat this FUD that Edge is just IE

Comment: I was talking about old versions of Edge which I found out I still had on my Windows 10 PC when I wrote that comment. As a result I realized it wasn't supporting the new standards, features and security updates we take for granted now, until I made sure I had the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

fetch, according to the specs, will throw a TypeError if the URL to be fetched contains credentials ("Request cannot be constructed from a URL that includes credentials").

This may sound reasonable (for security) and neglectable, because an additional "Authorization" header could be used if needed.

However, there's a problem if fetch inside a page shall load data relative to the base url of the page and **if that page's URL has credentials itself**. The browser will construct an URL for `fetch('data.json')` that contains credentials taken from the page and throw an error.

To me this appears like a browser bug - it's building the URL and could simply leave out credentials (what it does every other time anyway replacing it magically by "Authorisation" header). However, as it happens on both Chrome and Firefox, this may be intentional (although, IMO, the specs may leave room for another interpretation as well).

XMLHttpRequest, on the other hand, would load the requested resource happily even with credentials (see network tab in developer tools).

Hence, under certain circumstances, the behaviour of the page will change or even lead to an error - which we had to learn the hard way. We ended up building an absolute URL by using `windows.location` data.