# Fetch vs. AjaxCall

Tags: javascript, ajax, fetch-api

What is the difference between typical AJAX and Fetch API?

Consider this scenario:

```
function ajaxCall(url) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET', url);

    req.onload = function() {
      if (req.status == 200) {
        resolve(req.response);
      } else {
        reject(Error(req.statusText));
      }
    };
    req.onerror = function() {
      reject(Error("Network Error"));
    };
    req.send();
  });
}

ajaxCall('www.testSite').then(x => {
  console.log(x)
}) // returns html of site

fetch('www.testSite').then(x => {
  console.log(x)
}) // returns object with information about call
```

This is what the `fetch` call returns:

```
Response {type: "cors", url: "www.testSite", status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK"…}
```

Why does it return different things?

Is there a way for `fetch` to return the same thing as a typical AJAX call?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between the Fetch API and XMLHttpRequest?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35549547/what-is-the-difference-between-the-fetch-api-and-xmlhttprequest)

Comment: FYI: Fetch isn't supported by IE11 (although there's a Polyfill for it: https://github.com/github/fetch)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The Fetch API has built in methods for different datatypes.
For just regular text/html you'd use the `text()` method, which returns a promise as well, and chain it with another then call.

```
fetch('www.testSite').then( x => { 
    return x.text();
}).then( y => {
    console.log(y);
});
```

The built-ins for the returned content is as follows

- `clone()` - Creates a clone of a Response object.
- `error()` - Returns a
  new Response object associated with a network error.
- `redirect()` - Creates a new response with a different URL.
- `arrayBuffer()` - Returns a promise that resolves with an ArrayBuffer.
- `blob()` - Returns a promise that resolves with a Blob.
- `formData()` - Returns a promise that resolves with a FormData object.
- `json()` - Returns a promise that resolves with a JSON object.
- `text()` - Returns a promise that resolves with a USVString (text).

It also allows you to send things to the server, or add your own headers etc.

```
fetch('www.testSite', {
    method  : 'post',
    headers : new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }),
    body    : new FormData(document.getElementById('myform'))
}).then( response => {
    return response.json(); // server returned valid JSON
}).then( parsed_result => {
    console.log(parsed_result);
});
```

Comment: Only recently `fetch` was added the option to being [aborted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController/abort) (why was `fetch` originally released without a way of aborting is beyond me). *Ajax* can be *aborted* much easier.

Comment: A `Promise` cannot be aborted. This is, perhaps, the limitation of the initial implementation. I wonder how they have worked around this.

Comment: this can be shortened a bit with .then(response => response.json())

Answer (score 9):

Your ajaxCall is returning the responseText from the XMLHttpRequest object. It is filtering it out.

You need to read the response Text in the fetch code.

```
fetch('/foo/').then(x => x.text()).then(console.log)
```

You can also use `x.json()` or `x.blob()`

Comment: it outpupts undefined

Comment: @trolkura What’s the URL you’re testing it with? `www.testSite` is not a valid domain, but could be a valid directory or file name, which most likely doesn’t exist wherever you’re testing it.

Comment: ah sorry, meant to use `text()`

Comment: Super late comment here, but those Response methods (text(), blob(), json()) though return another Promise, which is what probably confuses some people.