# How can I correctly fetch the Riot API with JS?

Tags: javascript, riot-games-api

i've been trying to fetch some data from the riot's api, and I have a problem:

This is the important part of the code:

```
const getUsuario = async (name) => {
  const resp = await fetch(`${APIRUL}${name}${apikey}`, {
    method: 'GET',
    mode: 'no-cors',
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  });
  const { data } = await resp.json();
  return data;
};

getUsuario("user-name");
```

If i put **mode: cors**. I have a problem with CORS, but if I have as the example above, it shows up this:

```
champions.js:15 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at getUsuario (champions.js:15)
```

This is the line 15:

```
const { data } = await resp.json();
```

Comment: Are you sure the response you get back is json type?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure. But if i do it with postman I get the correct output.

Comment: In postman it should tell you what the content-type of the response is.

Comment: Yes, it says application/json;charset=utf-8

Comment: can you log `let textResponse = await resp.text()` ?

Comment: I dont get anything back if I do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a similar error to what you are seeing here: [fetch() unexpected end of input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45696999/fetch-unexpected-end-of-input)

Try printing the response before turning it to json and see if you see type `opaque`. This is specific to fetch requests made with mode `no-cors`. There seems to be a lot of restrictions to what you can do with this kind of response.

Updated: The RiotGames api server does not return the CORS headers for a reason. Most likely they don't want you to access their API directly from the browser. You need to have a backend make those api requests for you which can then forward the responses to your frontend.

Comment: I if do resp.text() I get undefined, and if I print the response before turning it to json I get type opaque. I don't know that to do with that

Comment: Are you sure about your request url is correct? Maybe there is a problem with URL/API Token parameter and you get 403 error without a body. Maybe...

Comment: @Knarf it's a CORS thing - the server probably isn't returning some CORS headers. Read this google article for a nice explanation: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch#response_types

Comment: I used the same url in postman and get what I want so I think it is correct.

Comment: Maybe your variable name is incorrect. In the code example, you written APIRUL instead of APIURL.

Comment: The browser has different restrictions than postman - are you sure you are meant to query the RiotGames api directly from the browser? As opposed to a backend that forwards the responses to your frontend?

Comment: I wanted to test it easily in the frontend, perhaps it is mandatory to do it from the server. The documentation doesn't explain it too much.

Comment: Yeah I'm reading elsewhere and that appears to be the case - I updated my answer. Annoying but at least you know what's wrong :)