# Fetch get API request using JavaScript failed to showing data in console but works in POSTMAN

Tags: javascript, postman, fetch-api, request-headers

I am not getting JSON data in console by requesting this API : https://amlocatapi.us-south.cf.appdomain.cloud/location with using this headers

```json
{
  method:'GET',
  headers:{
    'Authorization':'1q2w3e4r5t6yu7i8',
    'Content-Type':'application/json'
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
Hello
</body>
<script>
fetch('https://amlocatapi.us-south.cf.appdomain.cloud/location',
{
  method:'GET',
  headers:{
    'Authorization':'1q2w3e4r5t6yu7i8',
    'Content-Type':'application/json'
  }
}
).then(response => response.json())
.then(json => console.log(json))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: If you check dev tools console you see your error: _Access to fetch at from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy_ and also _Unexpected end of input_. Actually that empty object which you are logging is not your result but `console.log(err)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fetch() unexpected end of input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45696999/fetch-unexpected-end-of-input)

Comment: It is not solving my problem. If I remove authorization header from the request then It will show Unauthorized in response

Comment: Well `no-cors` [allows only limited set of headers in the request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#supplying_request_options) and `Authorization` is not one of them. Basically this is problem of server which you are trying to fetch data from (it has no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header) and your browsers problem which doesn't allow resources without that header. You can [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35588699/response-to-preflight-request-doesnt-pass-access-control-check) for more info.

Comment: aren't you simply get a CORS error? something like `Access to fetch at 'https://amlocatapi.us-south.cf.appdomain.cloud/location' from origin '...' has been blocked by CORS policy`... as that works fine from NodeJs using axios

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` header. Since you are making a GET request you don't need it. And what is the response coming from console? Did you check in the network requests?

Comment: It is not solving my problem. If I remove authorization header from the request then It will show Unauthorized in response.

Comment: I said content-type not authorization header. What is the response you get back from the server?