# SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input in fetch api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, fetch-api, rapidapi

if i do this->

```
fetch(
      //something,
      options
    )
      .then((response) => response.json() )
```

it gives me error **'SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input in fetch api'** but if i remove *.json()* after *response* like->

```
fetch(
      //something,
      options
    )
      .then((response) => response )
```

**it stops throwing error.**
can anyone explain me the issue

Comment: What does response look like? Can you show a console.log() of what the fetch returns?

Comment: "The json() method of the Response interface takes a Response stream and reads it to completion. It returns a promise which resolves with the result of parsing the body text as JSON.". That error message indicate that the response is not a valid JSON, and therefore it's unable to parse it into a JavaScript object. Try `console.log()` -ing the response to see what does the request returned

Comment: The _Unexpected end of JSON input_ error occurs also when you try to parse an invalid JSON string or an empty array, like `JSON.parse([])` or `JSON.parse("")`. - Your response may be empty.

Comment: That means, the response you get is not a valid JSON. It may look like one in the beginning (otherwise you'd get a different error) but at some point it just stops, unexpectedly as the error tells you. Hard to say what the reason is without further details

Comment: Try something like `.then(response=> response.text()).then(t => console.log(t))` to see what the actual response is

Comment: But yeah, of course it stops throwing an error about the invalid JSON, once you remove the JSON parsing...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45696999/fetch-unexpected-end-of-input

Answer (score -3):

as @iLittleWizard and @derpirscher said in the comment,

try

```
fetch(
      //something,
      options
    )
    .then(response=> response.text()).then(t => console.log(t))
```

in the log you can see the json response.
try copy & paste the logs to json validator site(like [devutils.org](https://devutils.org))

you can get hint from the site or you should copy & paste the response here for more help