# How to make a "simple" GET request if the resource doesn't allow CORS?

Tags: css, cors, w3c, w3c-validation, fetch-api

I'm trying to use W3C's CSS Validator Web Service API in a Chrome new tab extension. [The docs](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/manual.html) claim that a request is **a simple HTTP GET call to a URI**, so I figured this should work:

```
fetch('http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F&profile=css3&output=json')
.then((response) => {
  // do stuff with response
});
```

Unfortunately the promise fails and I get a message like:

> Failed to load. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on
>   the  requested resource. Origin is therefore not allowed access.

How am I supposed to make a "simple" `GET` request if the resource doesn't allow `CORS`?

Thanks!

Comment: _Not_ via client-side JavaScript?

Comment: I get this error: `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://blah-blah.com' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.` And if I set `{mode: 'no-cors'}` it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**2017-10-22 Update:** The [change for adding CORS support to the CSS Validator](https://github.com/w3c/css-validator/pull/81) was merged and pushed to production, so the following now works as-is:

```js
const validatorURL = 'https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator' +
  '?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F&profile=css3&output=json';
fetch(validatorURL)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(results => console.log(results))
```

---

**Original answer:**

The CSS Validator doesn’t send the necessary CORS response headers. To fix that, I’ve [raised a pull request with a change against the CSS Validator sources](https://github.com/w3c/css-validator/pull/81) that’ll enable your code snippet to work as-is. I’ll post an update here once the change is merged and pushed to production.

In the meantime, you can work around the issue by making your request through a CORS proxy:

```js
const proxyURL = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';
const validatorURL = 'http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator' +
  '?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F&profile=css3&output=json';
fetch(proxyURL + validatorURL)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(results => console.log(results))
```

For details abou why that works, see the *How to use a CORS proxy to get around “No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header” problems* section of the answer at *[No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource—when trying to get data from a REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe/43881141#43881141)*.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [register the allowed origin](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr#requesting-permission) for the extension's manifest:

```
  "permissions": [
    "http://jigsaw.w3.org/"
  ],
```

And you might need to [set the origin mode](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch#response_types) for the fetch function as well:

```
fetch(
 'http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F&profile=css3&output=json', 
  {mode: 'no-cors'})
.then((response) => {
  // do stuff with response
});
```

Comment: Setting `mode: 'no-cors'` will prevent the rest of that code from having any access to do stuff with the response. See the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43317967/handle-response-syntaxerror-unexpected-end-of-input/43319482#43319482

Answer (score 0):

From chrome web store you can add CORS Filter extension. just enable the filter before you run your code.

From [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en) you can add the filter to your chrome browser.