# Get request with fetch and react

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, fetch

This is probably a very dumb question, but I cant find any solution on the web, please dont bash me. I set up a create-react-app and want to display some data in a table.

This is my JSON:

```
[ {
  "unitid" : 29,
  "createddate" : 1510324778000,
  "latitude" : 49.402008056640625,
  "longitude" : 11.901968002319336,
  "senderid" : 6,
  "signalstrength" : 37
}, {
  "unitid" : 34,
  "createddate" : 1510563384000,
  "latitude" : 49.22679901123047,
  "longitude" : 12.845210075378418,
  "senderid" : 8,
  "signalstrength" : 0
},......
```

And my table needs a JSON Array with all the attributes in order to display every column correctly.

This is the code where I try to fetch the data from an endpoint of mine:

```
class App extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        vehicleList: [],
    };
}

componentDidMount(){
    fetch('endpoint-link', {mode: 'no-cors', method: 'get'})
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => {
            this.setState({vehicleList: result.vehicleList})
            console.log(result)
        })

        .catch(error => {
            this.setState({isLoaded: true, error})
            console.log(error)
        });
}

render() {
    const {vehicleList} = this.state;
    console.log(vehicleList);.......
```

When I open the Devtools in Chrome, go for "Network" I can see that the endpoint is known and the data is found, but somehow the fetch method is not loading the JSON into the Array.

Comment: Under "this is my JSON", you just have an array. It has no `vehicleList` property. And yet, you are putting `result.vehicleList` into your state. Does the JSON have a `vehicleList` property, or does it not?

Comment: No it doesn't. What would you recommend for this?

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON doesn't have a `vehicleList` property. It just has the array of vehicles. So you need to put that in your state:

```
this.setState({vehicleList: result})
```

Comment: It is still not working. When I open the Console in Chrome-Dev, I see empty arrays for the console logs I put in my code and also it seems like its jumping to the .catch error directly because its giving me this warning "Unexpected end of input".

Comment: @Aleks That would suggest that the JSON might not be valid. Are you sure that the JSON is valid? Can you copy it into a validator?

Comment: Just tested it and the two validators were giving me positive results. What else could be the problem?

Comment: @Aleks if you click the request in the Network tab and look at the Response tab, is the full JSON there?

Comment: @Aleks Not quite sure what else to suggest. Could you add the full error message and stack trace to the body of your question?

Comment: I found the problem. Its because of the mode:"no-cors". It is not possible to do it this way. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43317967/handle-response-syntaxerror-unexpected-end-of-input

Comment: @Aleks Ok, so you were specifying `no-cors` on a cross-domain request? Was the use of `result.vehicleList` instead of `result` (as I mentioned in my answer) also something that needed to be fixed, or was I mistaken about that?

Comment: It was not a difference. The same JSON was shown with both solutions.

Comment: @Aleks Huh? `this.setState({vehicleList: result.vehicleList})` and `this.setState({vehicleList: result})` can't both produce the same outcome. Which one worked in the end (successfully resulted in the vehicles being shown on the page)?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this -> `...{mode="no-cors"...}`
See this post in order to fix it: [Handle response - SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43317967/handle-response-syntaxerror-unexpected-end-of-input)