# Cant get desired response in react js from flask api

Tags: python, reactjs, flask

I am using the `fetch` library from `reactjs` for getting and pushing data to/from my `flask` API. But can't get the desired response from the my api.

This is my **flask api**:

```
@app.route('/adduser',methods=['POST'])
    def indx():
    data=request.get_json(force=True)
    email=request.get_json()["email"]
    password=request.get_json()['password']
    try:
        auth.create_user_with_email_and_password(email,password)
    except:
        userexists="User Already Exists"
    try:
        user=auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password(email,password)
        id = auth.get_account_info(user['idToken'])
        db.child("users").push(id)
    except:
        invalidCredentials="Wrong Credentials"
    if request.get_json(force=True):
        x={
            "name":"sarmad",
            "roll":"052"
        }
        s=json.dumps(x)
        return s
    else:
        return ""
```

This is **react js code:**

```
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/adduser', {
    mode:'no-cors',
 method: 'POST',
 headers: {
   'Accept': 'application/json',
   "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
 },
 body: JSON.stringify({
   'email': this.state.email,
   password: this.state.password,
   name: this.state.name,
//    userType: userTy,
   dob:this.state.DOB,
   address:this.state.Address,
   gender:'male',
   phone:'090078601',
//    roles:roles
 })
}).then((response) => response).then((responseJson) => {
  console.log(responseJson);
 //this.setState({pressed: false});
})
```

I need to receive the data passed back from the Flask API either as a `string` or `json`. This is my current response back:

```
Response {type: "opaque", url: "", redirected: false, status: 0, ok: false, …} body: (...) bodyUsed: false headers: Headers {} ok: false redirected: false status: 0 statusText: "" type: "opaque" url: "" _proto_: Response
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: **Response {type: "opaque", url: "", redirected: false, status: 0, ok: false, …}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: false
redirected: false
status: 0
statusText: ""
type: "opaque"
url: ""
__proto__: Response**
This is the response i get in inspect option of browser

Comment: Don’t use mode: 'no-cors'. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43262121/trying-to-use-fetch-and-pass-in-mode-no-cors/43268098#43268098 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43317967/handle-response-syntaxerror-unexpected-end-of-input-when-using-mode-no-cors/43319482#43319482. If you specify mode: 'no-cors', the browser blocks your frontend JavaScript code from accessing the response body and response headers. That’s what 'opaque' response means.

Answer (score 2):

Just do it with `.json()`

```
}).then((response) => response.json()).then((responseJson) => {
  console.log(responseJson);
 //this.setState({pressed: false});
})
```

Comment: Check again if you put `response.json()` with parentheses, because it seems that you return `response.json` as function.

Comment: QA ( @rana-sarmad-rajput), did this answer fixed your issue?