# no-cors opaque request for html resource fetch blocked by CORB

Tags: cors, fetch, cross-origin-read-blocking

I'm trying to fetch `html` file located at url `https://sub.app.test/html`  from `https://app.test` using `no-cors` mode but the response is blocked by CORB (cross-origin read blocking).

```
fetch('https://sub.app.test/html', { mode: 'no-cors'})
```

Why?

Comment: Even if you didn’t run into any CORB problem, specifying 'no-cors' mode will block your frontend JavaScript code from accessing the response body or response headers at all. For details, see the answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43262121/trying-to-use-fetch-and-pass-in-mode-no-cors/43268098#43268098 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/43319482/441757

Comment: @sideshowbarker yes, I'm aware that `no-cors` responses are usable only as a source for sivaleio elements since they aren't limited by SOP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though `no-cors` mode is used (so the response doesn't need to have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to be allowed) the request is blocked by CORB because an html content is considered a data resource (it may contain sensitive data). Any resource that has MIME type `text/html` (and html is sniffed in response body or `X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff` is set) will be blocked by CORB so that sensitive data cannot be leaked using speculative side-channel attacks like Spectre vulnerabilities (the resource won't be added to the site renderer's memory).

There are a few ways to bypass this constraint:

- serve the resource from the same origin (`app.test`)
- use `cors` mode (server needs to add correct `Access-Control` header)
- change MIME type to something other than `text/html` or don't set the header at all (hacky)

read more:

- https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/services/network/cross_origin_read_blocking_explainer.md
- https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/corb-for-developers