# Receiving Access-Control-Allow-Origin errors when submiting a form via Google Apps Script

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, iframe, cors

I am receiving the following errors when submiting an `HTML` `form` to `Google Sheets` via `Google Apps Script`:

> ```
> Origin https://example.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
>
> Fetch API cannot load https://script.google.com/macros/s/…/exec due to access control checks.
>
> Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: Origin https://example.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
> ```

On the server side, I’ve already set the `XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL` in order to load the response in an `iframe`:

```
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("Index").setXFrameOptionsMode(
  HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL
)
```

What am I missing?

---

Here is my form:

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].setAttribute("target", "Response")

document.addEventListener("submit", e => {
  const form = e.target
  
  const iframe = Object.assign(document.createElement("iframe"), {
    name: "Response"
  })
 
  document.body.innerHTML = iframe.innerHTML
  
  fetch(form.action, {
    method: form.method,
    body: new FormData(form)
  })
  
  e.preventDefault()
})
```

```html
<form action=https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzz-KveHder1A3CX8GcqZI6GR2MQj66PDRWNKoatIET_LXNqQs/exec method=post>  
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Select Foobar</legend>
    <label><input type=checkbox name=Foobar value=Foo>Foo</label>
    <label><input type=checkbox name=Foobar value=Bar>Bar</label>
    <label><input type=checkbox name=Foobar value=Baz>Baz</label>
  </fieldset> 
  <input type=submit value=Submit>
</form>
```

---

The form submits to this `Google Sheet`:

> https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10VHS6bozcdNFYcRskkoONMT8Rt-2CwJ_LJGQWdkTJq4/

---

*The web app is deployed with `Me` execution privileges and `Anyone, even anonymous` access.*

Comment: Kindly follow tag guidance : [tag:google-apps-script-web-application]     *Questions about web applications must include how the app is published: 1. Execute as"Me"/"User accessing the web-app". 2.Access:" Anyone"/"Anyone even anonymous"*

Comment: @TheMaster I updated the question. Thanks for the the info.

Comment: I see you already have a answer. IMO, the problem is with `new FormData(form)`. May be if you add `body:URLSearchParams(new FormData(form))` and/or set content type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, the request might not be preflighted

Comment: @TheMaster Could you please expand your comment to a full answer? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Tested your script. Tanaike is right. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54911076/ It seems any returned content with mimetype  `text/html` is blocked by default. My suggestions won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this answer?

I think that your issue is to return the value of `HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("Index")` with the POST method.

As a solution, for example, how about the following modification?

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the script of server side is modified.

#### Server side: Google Apps Script

```
function doPost(e) {

  // do something

  return ContentService.createTextOutput("ok");
}
```

### Note:

- **When you modified the script of Web Apps, please redeploy Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to Web Apps. Please be careful this.**

### References:

- [Class HtmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service)
- [Class ContentService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/content/content-service)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Tanaike, you’re always here when I’m desperately looking for help. So the problem is with using `fetch`? If I submit the form without any JavaScript, just by targeting the `iframe`, I get the desired response without any errors.

Comment: @Tzar Thank you for replying. I think that it's yes. I could also confirm about it. It seems that when `fetch` is used, `return HtmlService` occurs such issue.

Comment: Sensei, could you please help with this one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58847181/7840155

Comment: @Tzar Thank you for replying. I saw it. But unfortunately, I cannot understand about your goal. So I cannot think of the solution yet. I apologize for my poor English skill. When I could understand about it, I would like to think of it. On the other hand, an answer has already been posted, I think that it will resolve your issue.