# Parsing failed SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I am trying to retrieve the response from an API, but after using:

```
fetch("url").then(res=>res.json()),
```

I am getting unexpected end of input error in my code at the following line:

```
res => res.json(),
```

Please find below code and help me locate exactly where am I going wrong:-

```
static fetchCurrentServices(){      
   return   fetch("http://localhost:8080/portal-backend/services",   {
        mode: "no-cors",
        method: "GET" ,
        headers: {
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        } 
  })
  .then(
    res => res.json() 
  ).catch(function (ex) {
   console.log('parsing failed', ex)
    });
  }
```

Comment: The problem probably is in the response you're getting, which is not json or it's malformed json. You probably forgot to replace "localhost:port" in your url with something that makes more sense?

Comment: no actually i changed the url from original to the above due to privacy concerns , i am able to get proper response (proper json formatted response from the url), problem is still at rendering the response.
though the original url is : http://localhost:8080/portal-backend/services

Comment: Can you copy the response you're getting and pass it as a string to `JSON.parse` in your browser console? What does it say?

Comment: just go here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43317967/handle-response-syntaxerror-unexpected-end-of-input-when-using-mode-no-cors). similar issue with `mode: "no-cors"`

Comment: i am able to get the desired response with JSON.parse() in browser console, now trying it with code

Comment: after using JSON.parse(), following is the response

{currentServiceList: Array(2), message: "Edit the email id for profile"}
currentServiceList: (2) [{…}, {…}]
message: "Edit the email id for profile"
__proto__: Object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try below code i think you missed adding {} and added some more changes please look at it.

```
static fetchCurrentServices(){      
   return   fetch("http://localhost:8080/portal-backend/services",   {
        mode: "no-cors",
        method: "GET" ,
        headers: {
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        } 
  }).then(res =>{
     return new Promise((resolve) => {
       if (res) {
        res.json().then(json => resolve(json)).catch(() => resolve(null))
      } else {
        resolve(null)
     }
   })

  }).catch(function (ex) {
   console.log('parsing failed', ex)
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, but in my case this is not helpful. I want to know why it does not work? Is my JSON not valid? Why is my response not ok?

Comment: In your case if you get response as null then you may face this type of issue so you can make catch for that response is like below I mentioned

return new Promise((resolve) => {
      if (resp) {
        resp.json().then(json => resolve(json)).catch(() => resolve(null))
      } else {
        resolve(null)
      }
    })

By using catch on resp.json() - you might be silently suppressing genuine parsing errors too. So when there is no data or when data has parsing errors - your code always assumes only no data case

Comment: yes, i able to handle the issue with this piece of code, thanks :)
but the real issue is that in mode : "no-cors " i am suppressing cross-origin platform sharing between front-end and api , therefore even though api returns response , i get an opaque response and thus empty response. I on the other hand , want to get proper js response and map it on my component

Comment: Thanks , i was able to handle this by adding the following annotation on the server side code :-

@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:3000")
 @GetMapping(path="/services", produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)