# How did I populate vaadin-grid with fetch?

Tags: javascript, fetch, vaadin, vaadin-grid, lit-element

I am using lit-element and vaadin-grid to make a table. it is very similar to this example. https://stackblitz.com/edit/grid-renderers?file=grid-demo.js

However, it keeps telling me I have a syntax error
[image]

I can not figure out why. I can see the request coming through and sending a result back.

Here is some code from my element.

```
  static get properties() {
    return {
        rolls: {
            type: Array
          }
    };
}



 firstUpdated() {
        fetch('http://localhost:2241/api/micrographics/claims/01P78168', {
           mode: 'no-cors'          
          }).then(r=>console.log(r)).then(r => r.json())
          .then(data => {
            this.rolls = data.result;
          });

    }  


render() {
        return html`


      <p>Search Edit Table</p>


      <vaadin-grid multiSort id="valo-grid" .items="${this.rolls}" >

        <vaadin-grid-sort-column resizable width="2em" path="ID" header="ID">
        </vaadin-grid-sort-column >

        <vaadin-grid-sort-column resizable width="2em" path="Roll" header="Roll No">
        </vaadin-grid-sort-column >

        <vaadin-grid-sort-column resizable width="3em" path="Frame" header="Frame No">
        </vaadin-grid-sort-column >

        <vaadin-grid-sort-column resizable .renderer="${this.editTextRender}" 
         path="PolicyOcc_No" header="Policy/OccNo" width="11em">
        </vaadin-grid-sort-column >

        <vaadin-grid-sort-column resizable .renderer="${this.editDateRender}"
        path="ScanDate" header="Scan Date" width="10em" >
        </vaadin-grid-sort-column >

        <vaadin-grid-sort-column resizable width="2em" path="CompanyBranch" header="Company">
        </vaadin-grid-sort-column >

        <vaadin-grid-sort-column resizable .renderer="${this.editDateRender}"
         path="PurgeDate" header="Purge Date" width="10em">
        </vaadin-grid-sort-column >

        <vaadin-grid-column width="6em" .renderer="${this._boundEditButtonRender}"></vaadin-grid-column>
      </vaadin-grid>

        `;

    }
```

Here is a sample of my response

```
{"ResultList":[{"Id":"883","PolicyOcc_No":"01P168","CompanyBranch":"0","PurgeDate":"11/31/2019","ScanDate":"","Roll":"1057","Frame":"8","PolicyNo":" ","FileName":"cl.csv"},{"Id":"667","PolicyOcc_No":"01P78168/06","CompanyBranch":"01","PurgeDate":"12/31/2006","ScanDate":"05/19/2006","Roll":"452","Frame":"5","PolicyNo":"01P168","FileName":"cl.csv"}]}
```

If I take out `mode: 'no-cors'` then I get these errors. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation for `no-cors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/mode) states that

> In addition, JavaScript may not access any properties of the resulting Response.

which is what an *opaque* result means. So when the error message says to use `no-cors` if an opaque result fits your needs, it actually does not fit your needs, as it's not readable.

Perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43319482/3358029) is of help.

Comment: It had nothing to do with my JS code. I needed to set my API up for CORS.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2