# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data using fetch

Tags: javascript

I'm using this function

```
obtenerCursos:async function(){
                    const data = await fetch('cursos.json', {mode: 'no-cors'});
                    const cursos = await data.json();
                    commit('llenarCursos',cursos)
                }
```

I try to get data from local json file:

```
[
    {"nombre":"item1", "id":1},
    {"nombre":"item2", "id":2},
    {"nombre":"item3", "id":3}
]
```

But I'm not getting json data I get a object

```
Response
​
body: null
​
bodyUsed: false
​
headers: Headers
​
ok: false
​
redirected: false
​
status: 0
​
statusText: ""
​
type: "opaque"
​
url: ""
```

I'm not sure about what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handle response - SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input when using mode: 'no-cors'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43317967/handle-response-syntaxerror-unexpected-end-of-input-when-using-mode-no-cors)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> type: "opaque"
> ```

This means that JavaScript **cannot see the content** of the response.

Since JS can't see the content, the content it can see has zero length. So it gets to the end of the content before finding anything that would make it valid JSON.

It is opaque because you said:

> ```
> mode: 'no-cors'
> ```

Don't do that.

Comment: If I dont's use `{mode: 'no-cors'}` I have another problem because the cors request Its not http

Comment: @af1223345 — Then run a webserver so it is HTTP. You can't read a file that needs CORS permission to access by telling the browser you don't need CORS and it shouldn't do anything that requires it (which is what `mode: 'no-cors'` means).

Comment: ok, i'm running the file directly on the browser without server , this should be the problem

Comment: That is the problem. Use a webserver.