# Getting net::ERR_ABORTED 401 in my react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

Below is my react code snippet. I have verified that the token is correct using postman. Does anyone have ideas what might be missing here ?

```
export async function getData() {

    const url = buildUri();

    const auth = "Bearer " + await getAccessToken(); // api call to get access token
    console.log("Using auth: ", auth);

    var res = fetch(url, {
       method: 'GET',
       mode: 'no-cors',
       headers: {
           "Content-Type": "application/json",
           "Authorization": auth
       }
   }).then(response => {
       return response.json();
   }).catch((error) => {
       console.log("Error getting data: ", error);
   });
   console.log('got res: ', res);
}
```

Comment: check `GET` url in postman too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handle response - SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input when using mode: 'no-cors'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43317967/handle-response-syntaxerror-unexpected-end-of-input-when-using-mode-no-cors)

Comment: @RahulKumar yea i have verified the URL as well.

Comment: @Reyno sadly, it doesn't

Comment: @Nivedita GET url provides response using postman?

Comment: yes it does, I also tried with curl. I suspect this has something to do with 'no-cors' and my react localhost server but not sure why would it say 401.