# why i am getting blocked by CORS policy error even though i use cors Origin statement with my frontend url

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, cors

I have got 'blocked by CORS policy' error as mentioned below. I know this kind issue is reported in this portal many time. As suggested in one of the answers in this portal, I have used cors header 'Origin' with my frontend url. Please refer app.use statement in my server.js file. I am still getting same 'blocked by CORS policy' error. I am not facing this issue when is use postman. Can anyone please assist?

**Note:** In the frontend fetch statement, i used 'mode:'no-cors'. It helps me to avoid the below error. But, my response from backend becomes opaque response. As mentioned in another post([Handle response - SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input when using mode: 'no-cors'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43317967/handle-response-syntaxerror-unexpected-end-of-input-when-using-mode-no-cors)) in this portal, opaque response is probably because effect of setting no-cors mode is essentially to tell browsers, “Don’t let frontend JavaScript code access the response body or headers under any circumstances.”. So, i am not able to read the response(comes from backend) in my front end. I have tried with "mode:'cors'" as well as without mode statement also, no luck to fix this issue.

**Error:**

*Access to fetch at 'https://xxxxxx-xxxxxxx.el.r.appspot.com/signup/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx' from origin 'https://xxxxxxxxxxx-frontend.xxxx.r.xxxxxx.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.*

**My back-end(Node js): Server.js file**

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const routesHandler = require('./routes/handler.js');

// Imports the Google Cloud client library for Bunyan.
const lb = require('@google-cloud/logging-bunyan');

// Import express module and create an http server.
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'https://xxxxxxsale-frontend.el.r.xxxxxxx.com'
}));

async function startServer() {
    const {logger, mw} = await lb.express.middleware({
      logName: 'samples_express',
    });
    const app = express();

    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use('/', routesHandler);
  
    // Install the logging middleware. This ensures that a Bunyan-style `log`
    // function is available on the `request` object. This should be the very
    // first middleware you attach to your app.
    app.use(mw);
  
    // Setup an http route and a route handler.
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
      req.log.info('this is an info log message');
      res.send('hello world 1');
    });
  
    const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
  
    // `logger` can be used as a global logger, one not correlated to any specific
    // request.
    logger.info({port}, 'bonjour');
  
    // Start listening on the http server.
    const server = app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`http server listening on port ${port}`);
    });
  
    app.get('/shutdown', (req, res) => {
      res.sendStatus(200);
      server.close();
    });
  }
  
  startServer();
```

**My back-end(node js): handler.js file**

```
const app = express()
const router = express.Router();
const {getAuth} = require('firebase-admin/auth')
require("dotenv").config()

const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())





router.get('/addtweets', (req, res) => {
    const str = [
        {
            "name": "Codr Kai",
            "msg": "This is my first tweet!",
            "username": "codrkai"
        },
        {
            "name": "Samantha Kai",
            "msg": "React JS is so simple!",
            "username": "Arun"
        },
        {
            "name": "John K",
            "msg": "Sweep the leg!",
            "username": "johnk"
        }
    ];
    res.end(JSON.stringify(str));
});
 

router.post('/signup/:emailId',function (req, res) {
    let useremailT = req.params.emailId;
    console.log(req.body);
    //const pass = req.body.password;
    let spc1=useremailT.indexOf(" ");
    let len1=useremailT.length;
     pass = useremailT.substr(0,spc1);
     useremailT = useremailT.substr(spc1+1,len1-spc1-1);
     let spc2=useremailT.indexOf(" ");
     len1=useremailT.length;
     let useremail = useremailT.substr(0,spc2);
     let username  = useremailT.substr(spc2+1,len1-spc2-1);
    
    
    var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("../xxxxxxsales-19e4e-firebase-xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxx.json");

if (!admin.apps.length) {
    admin.initializeApp({
        credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
        origin:'*'
      });
}

getAuth()
  .getUserByEmail(useremail)
  .then((userRecord) => {
    // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
    //console.log(`Successfully fetched user data: ${userRecord.toJSON()}`);
    if (userRecord.emailVerified) {
            //console.log('Res 1:' , res);
            res.send({"message":"Exist"});
        } else {
            //console.log('Res 2:' , res);
            res.send({"message":"Pending"});
        }
    
  })
  .catch((error) => {
 getAuth()
   .createUser({
    email: useremail,
    emailVerified: false,
    password: pass,
    disabled: false,
    displayName:username
  })
  .then((userRecord) => {
     username = userRecord.displayName;
     //console.log('in Error before generateEmailVerificationLink');
        getAuth()
        .generateEmailVerificationLink(userRecord.email)
        .then((link) => {
            // Construct email verification template, embed the link and send
            // using custom SMTP server.
            // return sendCustomVerificationEmail(useremail, displayName, link);
            //console.log(link);
            var email = userRecord.email;
            res.send({link}); 
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            // Some error occurred.
            console.log('error 1:' +error);
            //res.end('Error');
            res.send({"message":"Error"});
        });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('error 2:' +error);
    //res.end('DBissue');
    res.end({"message":error});
    //res.send({"message":error});
  });
});  

});

router.post('/resendEmail', (req, res) => {
    const useremail = req.body.email;
    var username = ''
    var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("../xxxxxxsales-19e4e-firebase-xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxx.json");

if (!admin.apps.length) {
    admin.initializeApp({
        credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
      });
}

getAuth()
  .getUserByEmail(useremail)
  .then((userRecord) => {
    // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
    //console.log(`Successfully fetched user data: ${userRecord.toJSON()}`);
    if (userRecord.emailVerified) {
        res.end(JSON.stringify('Exist'));
    } else {
        username = userRecord.displayName;
        getAuth()
        .generateEmailVerificationLink(userRecord.email)
        .then((link) => {
            var email = userRecord.email;
            res.send({"message":"Registered"});
            send_mail(link,userRecord.email,username);    

        })
        .catch((error) => {
            // Some error occurred.
            console.log('some error');
            res.end('Error');
        });
    }
    
  })
  .catch((error) => {
            res.end(JSON.stringify('UserNotFound'));    
  })
  
});  

router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    const useremail = req.body.email;
    const pass = req.body.password;
    var username = ''
    var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("../xxxxxxsales-19e4e-firebase-xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxx.json");

if (!admin.apps.length) {
    admin.initializeApp({
        credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
      });
}

getAuth()
  .getUserByEmail(useremail)
  .then((userRecord) => {
    // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
    //console.log(`Successfully fetched user data: ${JSON.stringify(userRecord)}`);
    if (userRecord.emailVerified) {
        res.end(JSON.stringify(userRecord.displayName));
    } else {
        res.end(JSON.stringify('Pending'));
    }
    
  })
  .catch((error) => {
            // Some error occurred.
           //console.log('some error');
            res.end('Error');
        });
  });

const send_mail=(link,email,username) =>{
let { text } = 'Welcome'
  const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

let transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 2525,
    // secure: true,
    auth: {
        user: "xxxxxxxx.xx",
        pass: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    },
    debug: true,
    logger: true
});

let mailTransporter = nodemailer.createTransport(transport);
 transport.sendMail({
  from: process.env.MAIL_FROM,
  to: email,
  subject: "Email verification",
  ContentType: "multipart/alternative",
ContentType: 'text/plain', charset:"UTF-8", format:'flowed', delsp:'yes',
ContentTransferEncoding: 'base64',
  html: `MY HTML CODE HERE `
});

}
router.get('/send_mail',cors(), (req, res) => {
    let { text } = 'Welcome'
    const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: process.env.MAIL_HOST,
        port: process.env.MAIL_PORT,
        auth: {
            user: process.env.MAIL_USER,
            pass: process.env.MAIL_PASS
        }
    })

     transport.sendMail({
        from: process.env.MAIL_FROM,
        to: "test@test.com",
        subject: "test email",
        html: `<div className="email" style="
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 20px;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        line-height: 2;
        font-size: 20px; 
        ">
        <h2>Here is your email!</h2>
        <p>${text}</p>
    
        <p>All the best, Darwin</p>
         </div>
    `
    })
})

module.exports = router;
```

My Front end(React):

```
if (form.email !== ''    && typeof(form.email)    !== undefined
       && form.password !== '' && typeof(form.password) !== undefined && errMessage === "") {
         //props.saveLogin(form);
         const databody =
               form.password+" "+form.email+" "+form.fname;

               // const data = await fetch('https://xxxxxxx-xxxxxx.el.r.xxxxxxx.com/signup/'+databody,
               // {
               //  method: "POST",
               //  mode:'no-cors',
               // headers:{headers}
               // }
               console.log('data Y1:'+ databody);
         const data = await fetch('https://xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxx.el.r.xxxxx.com/signup/'+databody,
                     {
                      method: "POST",
                      mode: 'cors',
                      headers: {

                      "Accept": "application/json",
                          "Content-Type": "application/json"
                        }
                     }
                     ).then((response) => {
                       console.log(response);
                       if (!response.status) {

                         //console.log("complete");
                         return response.json();
                       }
                       else {
                           throw new Error('Something went wrong');
                       }

                     })
                     .then((responseJson) => {
                       const items =  responseJson.message;
                       //console.log(items);
                       //console.log("error new");
                       if (items==='Pending') {
                         alert('Email id already exist. Kindly check your inbox and verify.');
                       }
                       else if (items==='Registered') {
                         //alert('Email id registered successfully. Kindly check your inbox and verify.');
                         //alertA.show('Email id registered successfully. Kindly check your inbox and verify.');
                         CreateUser();
                       }
                       else if (items==='DBissue') {
                         alert('Db issue. Please try after sometime.');
                       }
                       else if (items==='Error') {
                         alert('Error. Please try after sometime.');
                       } else if (items==='Exist')
                       {
                         //console.log(items);
                         alert('Email is already registered. You may proceed to Login.');
                       }
                       else
                       {
                         alert('Error occurred. Please after sometime.')
                       }

                     })
                     .catch((error) => {
                       alert(error);
                     });

      
     }
     else if(errMessage !== ""){
           console.log('in errMessage block');
           alert(errMessage);
     }
```

Answer (score 3):

In your error description

> Access to fetch at 'https://xxxxxx-xxxxxxx.el.r.appspot.com/signup/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx' from origin 'https://xxxxxxxxxxx-frontend.xxxx.r.xxxxxx.com' has been blocked by CORS policy:

Your frontend seems to be on origin `https://xxxxxxxxxxx-frontend.xxxx.r.xxxxxx.com`. But CORS on the server is configured to only allow requests from `https://xxxxxxsale-frontend.el.r.xxxxxxx.com`.

To fix this, either move your frontend to `https://xxxxxxsale-frontend.el.r.xxxxxxx.com`

or, and that is easier, change the CORS origin to `https://xxxxxxxxxxx-frontend.xxxx.r.xxxxxx.com`

from:

```js
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'https://xxxxxxsale-frontend.el.r.xxxxxxx.com'
}));
```

to:

```js
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'https://xxxxxxxxxxx-frontend.xxxx.r.xxxxxx.com'
}));
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: sorry.. it is masking error.. both are same.. i did not put 'x' properly in my question.. i have used correct url 'https://xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxx.el.r.xxxxx.com' in cors also.

Comment: I am able to fix it.

Comment: What was the error? I couldn't find any