# after receiving the request, the response comes, but the request object is empty

Tags: javascript, vue.js, servlets, cors, fetch

there was a problem with the fetch request to the express server via vue cli, there was an error with "cors", fixed it, now I get the request, but I see it in the networke of the developer tool [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24A27.png) but the console is empty [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhY5E.png) here is the code:

```
methods: {
async getInfo () {
  const response = await fetch('https://ksjkfsjdbnfksjfksjf744.netlify.app/.netlify/functions/api/demo',
    { mode: 'no-cors' })
  const responseString = await response
  const responseObject = await JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(responseString))
  console.log(responseString)
  console.log(responseObject)
}
```

can't solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

[Fetch documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

> The Response object, in turn, does not directly contain the actual JSON response body but is instead a representation of the entire HTTP response. So, to extract the JSON body content from the Response object, we use the json() method, which returns a second promise that resolves with the result of parsing the response body text as JSON.

In summary, to get your JSON, use `json()` method on the returned fetch response

```js
const response = await fetch('https://ksjkfsjdbnfksjfksjf744.netlify.app/.netlify/functions/api/demo',
    { mode: 'no-cors' })
const responseObject = await response.json()
console.log(responseObject)
```

#### Edit:

This will only work if `mode: 'no-cors'` is removed. Reasoning is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43319482/6225326).  Instead of trying to bypass CORS, the better solution is to add the frontend's origin to be allowed by CORS on the backend.

Comment: json() did not help

Comment: I wasn't familiar with it before, but it looks like an issue with using `mode: 'no-cors'`.  The response body is not **accessible to frontend javascript code** when using this mode (but still seeing it in the network tab is expected). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43319482/6225326) that goes into more detail.  The ultimate solution will be to modify your backend API and add your frontend URL as an allowed CORS origin.