# How to get a File() or Blob() from an URL in javascript?

Tags: javascript, file, url, blob, firebase-storage

I try to upload an image to the Firebase storage from an URL (with `ref().put(file)`)(www.example.com/img.jpg).

To do so i need a File or Blob, but whenever I try `new File(url)` it says "not enough arguments“…

EDIT:
And I actually want to upload a whole directory of files, that’s why i can’t upload them via Console

Comment: Which environment are you running Javascript in? `File` can't take a URL and fetch it for you, you'll have to fetch it, read its data and create the `File` object with that data.

Comment: Yup, javascript. And you where right, thx so much for the fast answer ^^

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Try using the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). You can use it like so:

```js
fetch('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/77/Delete_key1.jpg')
  .then(res => res.blob()) // Gets the response and returns it as a blob
  .then(blob => {
    // Here's where you get access to the blob
    // And you can use it for whatever you want
    // Like calling ref().put(blob)

    // Here, I use it to make an image appear on the page
    let objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    let myImage = new Image();
    myImage.src = objectURL;
    document.getElementById('myImg').appendChild(myImage)
});
```

```html
<div id="myImg"></div>
```

As of January 2024, the fetch API has about [98% browser support](https://caniuse.com/#search=fetch) worldwide, with basically just IE missing it. You can get that to near 100% using a [polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch), which I recommend if you're still targeting IE.

Comment: why use two .thens instead of just one which does res.blob at the beginning

Comment: res.blob() returns a promise, so we need to wait for it to resolve before accessing the contents: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/blob

Comment: You will probalby get error "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource", if so you can use url proxy like proxy= https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ (or setup your own) then url = proxy + url, and use proxied url to fetch data.  Here is a broad answer to this problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/43268098/9253363

Answer (score 5):

@James answer is correct but it is not compatible with all browsers. You can try this jQuery solution :

```js
$.get('blob:yourbloburl').then(function(data) {
  var blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'audio/wav' });
});
```

Comment: This is not a pure javascript solution but a jQuery one, you should definitely mention that in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It did not work until I added credentials

```
fetch(url, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
      },
      credentials: 'include'
 })
```

Answer (score 1):

```javascript
async function url2blob(url) {
  try {
    const data = await fetch(url);
    const blob = await data.blob();
    await navigator.clipboard.write([
      new ClipboardItem({
        [blob.type]: blob
      })
    ]);
    console.log("Success.");
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.name, err.message);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

If you are using homepage in package.json then ypu have to use:

CurrentUrl: http://localhost:3008/tempAppHomepageFromPackageJson/

```
const file: File = this.state.file;
const localUrlToFile = URL.createObjectURL(file);
const fileHash = localUrlToFile.split('/');
const objectUrl = location.href + fileHash[fileHash.length - 1];
```

objectUrl is the local url to file. For example to show in runtime you uploading file.

Second solution is (if you have no homepage in package.json):

```
const file: File = this.state.file;
const objectUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
```

Third solution (Not working in safari):

```
const file: File = this.state.file;
let reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
const objectUrl = reader.result as string;
```

Enjoy ;)