# How to append a file to a FormData() from a URL or file on server rather than a file input

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, form-data

I'm working on a piece of code using the **Stripe Connect API** where the user can send a visual from an `input type="file"` to an AJAX call via jQuery, this way:

```js
var form_file = new FormData();
form_file.append('file', document.querySelector('input#file_to_send').files[0]);
```

When the user submits the form, I copy the visual in a folder on my server via PHP and keep its name in a session variable.
If something is incorrect or missing in the form, the user goes back to the same page, where the visual is shown in a `img` element under the `input type="file"` one, so the user knows that their visual has been taken into consideration.

After that, I need to do send the file in an AJAX call again... Except that this time, the file cannot be selected from the `input type="file"` anymore, the only accessible source I have would be to take it's name from the `img` element in JavaScript.

Now, if I do this:

```js
var form_file = new FormData();
form_file.append('file', $('img#visual').attr('src'));
```

And send this via the same AJAX call:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://uploads.stripe.com/v1/files',
    type: 'POST',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' },
    data: form_file
}).fail(function(e) {
    console.log('fail: ' + e);
}).done(function(e) {
    console.log('file uploaded: ' + e.id);
});
```

My question, you guessed it, is: is there a way to/how should I do to send a file not from an `input` element as a source, but a defined path taken from an `img` element?

Comment: I would do it in PHP. Your formData sends the URL, then PHP uses the URL with a cURL request or file_get_contents().

Comment: Not sure how to do that... would you please draw a little draft of that maybe? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read your question a second time. If I understand correctly you need to **send a cross-domain AJAX request** to stripe.com, so you are not controlling the PHP code on the server side, right?

**SHORT ANSWER:**

The easiest way would be to do your form check in Javascript instead of PHP, so you won't need to go back and "lose" the selected input file.

---

... ***BUT*** if you really need/want to **send a cross-domain file using only its URL**,

then you'll need to convert **Data URI to File then append to FormData** :

1/ Get you image base64 value

```
function toDataUrl(url, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function() {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function() {
            callback(reader.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
    };
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.send();
}
```

2/ Convert the base64 image to Blob :

```
function DataURIToBlob(dataURI: string) {
    const splitDataURI = dataURI.split(',')
    const byteString = splitDataURI[0].indexOf('base64') >= 0 ? atob(splitDataURI[1]) : decodeURI(splitDataURI[1])
    const mimeString = splitDataURI[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0]

    const ia = new Uint8Array(byteString.length)
    for (let i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++)
       ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i)

    return new Blob([ia], {
       type: mimeString
    })
 }
```

3/ Send you Blob with FormData :

```
const file = DataURIToBlob(imgBase64)
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('upload', file, 'image.jpg')
```

Sources :

- [CONVERT Image url to Base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22172604/convert-image-url-to-base64)
- https://pretagteam.com/question/how-to-append-an-image-from-url-to-a-formdata-javascript
- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-convert-data-uri-to-file-then-append-to-formdata/

---

**Edit:**

You could speed up phase 1 and 2 by using the **Fetch API** to get the image Blob directly.

(WARNING: not compatible with IE)

Source : [How to get a File() or Blob() from an URL in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44070437/how-to-get-a-file-or-blob-from-an-url-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

I was able to achieve what I wanted! Here is the code I ended up with:

```
var visual_source = 'upload/file-source.png';
var visual_ext = visual_source.split('.').pop();
var visual = await fetch(visual_source);
console.log(visual);
var visual_as_blob = await visual.blob();
console.log(visual_as_blob);
var visual_as_file = new File([visual_as_blob], 'file-name-renamed.' + visual_ext, { lastModified: new Date().getTime(), type: visual_as_blob.type });
console.log(visual_as_file);
form_file.append('file', visual_as_file);
```

I added a console.log() at each step of this if anyone needs this code and wants to see the result of what is happening step by step. The steps being:

- We fetch the file from a given url (here, a file on the server in a "upload" folder)
- We set the fetched data as a blob
- We transform the blob as a file
- We are then able to append() the file to the FormData() element

After that, it can be sent via ajax to the Stripe API.