# Apollo GraphQL response is invisible in chrome devtools

Tags: ajax, reactjs, google-chrome-devtools, graphql, react-apollo

I am learning GraphQL with `react-apollo` and wanted to look request in Chrome Devtools under Networks tab, but unfortunately I could see only this.
[image]

Though I could see response with chrome extension called `GraphQL Network`.
I am very curious, what can cause such behavior?

As I know it is impossible to hide AJAX response.

**UPDATE**

Status of request is success 200 and I can see data from server successfully, but I noticed one thing, that type of request instead of `xhr` is `fetch`.

[image]

I guess it is because used `fetch` API, though don't know should be any differences between them, aren't they same XHR?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because of the CORS. I presume you've not either configured the server to allow cross origin request or you have added *'no-cors'* in the request header.
In that case we are telling the browser to make the request, but we won't be allowed to view the response.(See [Trying to use fetch and pass in mode: no-cors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43262121/trying-to-use-fetch-and-pass-in-mode-no-cors))
However, surprisingly on checking developer tools for Firefox browser, I could see the response in the developer tools.

So as a solution, I would recommend you to configure your server config to allow *cors* request and other *cors* related parameters. See [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/260163) for configuration values example if you are confused.

Note: For Drupal GraphQL users, It might be a wise idea to create a copy of `default.services.yml` => `services.yml` and change the cors configuration values in `services.yml` file.