# Enable CORS in fetch api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cors, fetch-api

I am getting the following error message that unable me to continue

> Failed to load https://site/data.json: Response to preflight request
>   doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>   header is present on the requested resource. Origin
>   'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque
>   response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to
>   fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
>       localhost/:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

I am trying to enable `CORS` in my react js file but I was not able to get the expected result.  I have installed a chrome extension and it work. But to use this in production site, I need to enable it inside my code. How should I properly arrange the code to enable the `CORS`.

```
fetch(URL, {
  mode: 'cors',
  headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'
  }
})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
```

Comment: CORS must be handled server-side.

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` should be response header, client request is *invalid*

Comment: I think `CORS` can be enabled in client-side too.

Comment: hm, so with the error message above, according to the link posted, it seems like the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` must be enabled from `https://site/:` and not in my `http://localhost:8080`. If I understand it in simplicity.

Comment: What Chrome extension did you use? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moesif-origin-cors-change/digfbfaphojjndkpccljibejjbppifbc/ This one?

Answer (score 62):

Browser have cross domain security at client side which verify that server allowed to fetch data from your domain. If `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` not available in response header, browser will disallow to use response in your JavaScript code and throw exception at network level. You need to configure `cors` at your server side.

You can fetch request using `mode: 'no-cors'`. In this situation browser will not throw execption for cross domain, but browser will not give response in your javascript function.

So in both condition you need to configure `cors` in your server or you need to use custom proxy server.

Comment: What if I'm trying to scrape Google results? Like, I want to request `https://www.google.com` from my client code and parse the results. Is it possible? I'm getting the same error that he was getting. Does it mean that google.com does not allow CORS requests to its main search page? Thanks.

Comment: If you want to fetch any other server like google or facebook and that server doesn't provide access, you might need  a server to handle this. In server you can fetch response from google and send back to client.

Comment: I think is a typo, it's `no-cors` that returns an opaque response, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/43268098/6324591

Comment: This answer is wrong on so many levels...

Comment: @Christian feel free to correct it.

Comment: @Amesys SO guidelines/rules specify improving answers (e.g. fixing typos, syntax highlighting etc), _not correcting the content of the answer_ or changes that affected the meaning.

Comment: @Christian agreed but nothing prevents you from issuing your own answer, and given your 1st reply I'm sure it would bring something interesting to this topic (not being sarcastic here).