# How to resolve CORS error in Fetch API js

Tags: javascript, cors, fetch, fetch-api

I want to fetch json from my subdomain (File Hosting Server) , but it gets the following error:

**Reason: CORS request did not succeed)**

**(Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing**

my similar code:

```
async function getData(url = '', data = {}) {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'get',
    mode: 'no-cors',
    headers: {
       'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'
    },
  });
  return response.json();
}
```

I add

```
headers: {
}                               'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'
```

but don't work.

I add

```
mode: no-cors
```

to code, fetch file but return response status 0 , mode: 'opaque'.

please help me.

Comment: Please add the actual fetch code as a [mcve]?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enable CORS in fetch api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51017702/enable-cors-in-fetch-api)

Comment: You need to add those headers to the server response at `url`, you can't do it from the fetch request.

Comment: You have to set this header at server in the response. Not in the request. 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CORS is configured through server-side, so you need to configure on your File Hosting Server

Answer (score 3):

if your host a PHP file file what you went to call in a other PHP file you will need  lot of times to add this code in the PHP file thet you want to call at line_2

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you know what you are trying to achieve here. Fetch with CORS use case is very tricky. CORS is driven by server settings. All the headers ACCESS-CONTROL-* are set at the server end.

Access-Control-Allow-Origin is for CORS, and the client honor this header when dealing with the cross-origin request. The server sends this header in the response. From the server end, you have to pass this header. In your response, you have to pass this header.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Or if you are dealing with credentials (Wild card not supported here):-

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://foo.example
```

Reference:-

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch