# Can not post request in HTML JS | No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jdoodle

I'm making a Java Compiler website for myself and I'm using JDoodle 
In the document of this API, shows NodeJS code execute function
(https://docs.jdoodle.com/integrating-compiler-ide-to-your-application/compiler-api)

and I'm using javascript in html so I change a little bit to

```js
// using jQuery
$.ajax({
        url,
        type: 'post',
        data,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    })
```

but it gave me this error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://stage.jdoodle.com/execute' from origin has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I also tried `$.post` and [Why does my JavaScript code receive a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error, while Postman does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-code-receive-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-i) but still the same. 
Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable header on the server side.

This has been asked before [Enable CORS in fetch api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51017702/enable-cors-in-fetch-api)

Alternatively you can ignore CORS with a flag.

Comment: i tried to find some ways to enable CORS in fetch api/jQuery post/ajax but still got the same error

Comment: No, the server provides it in the response headers. Alternatively you can try https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere

Comment: i tried like docs but still got that error