# How to fix the "set the request's mode to 'no-cors'" error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oauth, cors

I am currently using yahoo weather API to fetch weather data. I am getting below error. Please help.

> Access to fetch at
> 'https://weather-ydn-yql.media.yahoo.com/forecastrss?location=sunnyvale,ca&format=json'
> from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
> mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I have tried to do google, but none of solution worked for me

Comment: Possible answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/43268098/2627022

Comment: add proxy ='https://api.codetabs.com/v1/proxy?quest=' before your url

Answer (score 44):

You can set the request mode to 'no-cors' like so:

```
fetch(url, {
    mode: "no-cors",
    ...
})
```

**But**, as *goto1* described in the comment below, it will usually not be the solution you are looking for:

@goto1

> If you're getting CORS issues this is not the solution. If the API
> endpoint is something that you control, then you have to fix those
> CORS issue there. If the API endpoint is not something that you
> control, then you have to proxy your request through a server that
> does have CORS enabled.

Comment: If you're getting `CORS` issues **this is not** the solution. If the `API` endpoint is something that you control, then you have to fix those `CORS` issue there. If the `API` endpoint is not something that you control, then you have to `proxy` your request through a server that does have `CORS` enabled.

Comment: A description of the fetch api's cors behavior and settings: https://javascript.info/fetch-crossorigin

Answer (score 6):

No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled

So, First of all you have to change your CORS from browser :
Here is the Link of that , download it and it will install by it self.

visit:https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moesif-origin-cors-change/digfbfaphojjndkpccljibejjbppifbc?hl=en-US

Name : Moesif Origin & CORS Changer

NOTE: Make sure it turns ON while you running your page.