# Access blocked by CORS headers

Tags: django, reactjs

I am working on a project with Django that serves data through API via Django Rest Framework on a React frontend. The Browsable API works fine, however, the react frontend is giving an error in the console.

I have installed django-cors-headers successfully.

```
import './App.css';

  class App extends Component {
      state = {
        products: []
      };

      async componentDidMount() {
        try {
          const res = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/');
          const products = await res.json();
          this.setState({
            products
          });
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e);
        }
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            {this.state.products.map(products => (
              <div key={products.id}>
                <h1>{products.prodName}</h1>
                <span>{products.description}</span>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default App;
```

Access to fetch at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: and you have both added it in `INSTALLED_APPS` and added `CorsMiddleware`?

Comment: I have added them both respectively

Comment: cros has to be allowed from api end as well

Comment: @BillySomers give a look at [Trying to use fetch and pass in mode: no-cors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43262121/trying-to-use-fetch-and-pass-in-mode-no-cors)

Answer (score 0):

these are parameters to check:
1. Add this line in the MIDDLEWARE in (setting.py)

```
'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
```

2. make sure that you have this:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
   'localhost:3000/'
)
```

3. Also Check This :

```
CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = (
    'DELETE',
    'GET',
    'OPTIONS',
    'PATCH',
    'POST',
    'PUT',
)
```

all of this prameters in your setting file (setting.py)

4. You write fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/') 
   so in your url.py make sure about back slash:

```
path('products/', views.products,name='products')
```