# How to log the response coming from fetch api

Tags: javascript, promise, request, fetch, response

I am using Promise to log the response from an api. But everytime the body is logging in as null. Most probably due to async call

For calling api from fetch.

```
function getDetails(url){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fetch(url, {mode: 'no-cors'}).then(res => {
            resolve(res);      
        }, error => {
            console.log(err);
        })
    })
}

var u = "https://get.geojs.io/v1/ip/country.json";
getDetails(u).then(function(resp){
    console.log(resp);    
})
```

I expect the response of the api in console

Comment: `fetch()` already returns a `Promise`, hence `new Promise(...)` is unnecessary

Comment: If I just do fetch and .then() in the function without returning anything still the body is null

Comment: `fetch()` returns a [`Response` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/Response).

Comment: function getDetails(url){
    fetch(url, {mode: 'no-cors'}).then(res => {
       console.log(res) ;
    },error => {
     console.log(err);
    })
}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to use fetch and pass in mode: no-cors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43262121/trying-to-use-fetch-and-pass-in-mode-no-cors). Don’t use 'no-cors' mode.

Answer (score 3):

[`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) already returns a `Promise` so get rid of the `new Promise(...)` part

```
function getDetails(url) {
    return fetch(...).then(...);
}
```

`fetch()` returns a [`Response` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) and not something that has already been parsed for you. You have to call [`.json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json) on it to get the response parsed by `JSON.parse()`.

```
function getDetails(url) {
    return fetch(url, {mode: 'no-cors'}).then(response => response.json());
}
```

This should already work, but with your setup will throw a syntax error:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

To get this fixed remove `mode: 'no-cors'`

Adding it all together will give us:

```js
function getDetails(url) {
    return fetch(url).then(response => response.json());
}

var u = "https://get.geojs.io/v1/ip/country.json";
getDetails(u).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
})
```