# Api call cause error 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: reactjs, cors

I am trying to call an api but it is giving me following error :

> Access to fetch at 'https://someapi.url/profile?FullName=sadaf&DateFrom=2000-01-01' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I am using react and the code is :

```
try {
        let url = `https://someapi.url/profile?FullName=sadaf&DateFrom=2000-01-01`;
        let response = await fetch(url,{
            mode: 'cors', // no-cors,
            credentials: 'include',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            "Accept": 'application/json',
            'Origin' : 'http://localhost:3000'
                //'Content-Type': 'text/xml'
                // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
              },
        });

        this.setState(() => {
            return {
                searchResults : response
            }
        })
      } catch (error) {

        console.error(error);
      }
```

please guide what to do

Comment: you have to enable `CORS` on your server.

Comment: but on browser and postman it is working fine

Comment: that's expected; `CORS` restrict resource access from client javascript code only

Comment: when i set mode = 'no-cros' it give me empty respose with these values  {type: "opaque", url: "", redirected: false, status: 0, ok: false, …}

Comment: you mean if call the same from express server it will run ?

Comment: yes it will succeed from express. `CORS` is a browser security feature.

Comment: it's the browser that blocks the response.

Comment: adding no-cors will not solve the problem check here for more info
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43262121/trying-to-use-fetch-and-pass-in-mode-no-cors

Comment: `no-cors` only makes the response unusable. You have to enable `CORS` on the server.

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS), there is nothing wrong with the front-end code.

> Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is a mechanism that uses
>   additional HTTP headers to tell browsers to give a web application
>   running at one origin, access to selected resources from a different
>   origin.

To fix this issue, the server should set the CORS headers,
See [here](https://enable-cors.org/server.html) on how to enable CORS for your server

If your server is running express you need to set cors like this,

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  // update to match the domain you will make the request from
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "YOUR-DOMAIN.TLD"); 
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

or use the cors [middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html) for express

Comment: there's cors middleware for express: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html