# Using the fetch API to query an endpoint to get a json response and getting back an empty response error

Tags: javascript, rest, fetch

Please forgive the long debug info and code. I figure its all relevant.

Im trying to query an api endpoint to get a ticket back.  I query using postman and get the ticket response back as text that is shown in the headers tab.  However, I want to use java script to get that ticket back and do other stuff with it.  When i run the script, it logs an error to the console:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at FetchDemo.html:48
(anonymous) @ FetchDemo.html:54

Promise.catch (async)
getTicket @ FetchDemo.html:53
```

the response i get is this:

```
type: "opaque"
url: ""
redirected: false
status: 0
ok: false
statusText: ""
headers: Headers {}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
__proto__: Response
```

My code is below:

```
<script>

let URL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/';
let TabURL = 'http://15.222.0.10/trusted/?username=admin';

document.getElementById("getTicket").addEventListener('click',getTicket);



function getTicket() {
    console.log("in side getTicket");
    //setup an options array to pass into the fetch call
    let options = {
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'no-cors',
        headers: {
            'Accept' : 'application-json,*/*',
            'Content-Type' : 'application:json'
        }
    };


    console.log(TabURL);
    console.log(options);
    fetch (TabURL,options)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });

}

</script>
```

Comment: In the above, what lines correspond to lines 48 and 54 in your original code?

Comment: The `status: 0` and `ok: false` tell us that the fetch failed. If you're doing this in a browser (as you appear to be), that's probably because of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) preventing access. Look for an error talking about a cross-origin being blocked. See: [*Why does my JavaScript code get a “No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource” error when Postman does not?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-code-get-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-pr)

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43262121/trying-to-use-fetch-and-pass-in-mode-no-cors

Answer (score 1):

From the specs:

> An opaque filtered response is a filtered response whose type is "opaque", URL list is the empty list, status is 0, status message is the empty byte sequence, header list is empty, and body is null.

The reason you're getting an opaque response, is because you use the `no-cors` flag. If you want to do cross-domain requests such as these, you need CORS.

- https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-filtered-response-opaque
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/type

Comment: Of course, if they remove the `no-cors`, they'll probably get an error because of the SOP...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: correct. Cross-domain requests require actual CORS headers. You can't really cheat

Comment: Frankly, this just seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-code-get-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-pr to me (sadly, I marked it "unclear" first, so...). But perhaps the `no-cors` part is new.

Comment: Nope, it's a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43262121/trying-to-use-fetch-and-pass-in-mode-no-cors.

Comment: Ok, i understand the issue with cors.  However, if I don't have access to the server code (ie, its a seperate piece vendor software), how do i fix the issue?  I thought putting the no-cors in the header was a solution, however I don't even get my response back without it.  

Can you guys help?

(also, sorry about the duplicate.  I searched briefly and didn't find that one)

Comment: @ChrisGauthierWinnipeg the idea of CORS is to explicitly allow other domains to access your server. If you don't have the ability to change server headers, you cannot make this request. If you did, there would be a major security problem. Your only real option is to use a different server to access the original API on your behalf. As a sort of proxy.

Comment: By the way, just so this doesn't get un-answered.  The solution i wrote to complete this task was to take the rest call out of the browser-viewable java script file.  I built an application in spring boot that used the rest-template api to take the browser out of the picture completely.  I am now using angular to call the rest point on the boot application.  I still have issues because spring boot seems to be generating a text response and angular seems to want java script, but Im working through that now.  Thanks for your help, gents.

Comment: @ChrisGauthierWinnipeg, this makes sense and exactly what i more or less suggested. Best way to call the API is to do it server-side yourself, where you have 0 restrictions

Comment: Can you possibly give me a resource on doing that?  That will save me some search time (which i don't mind, but not sure i understand the technique enough to do so)

Comment: I don't really have a resource, but to sum it up: You need your own backend (like Spring) and in this backend you make the rest call. Then your frontend can call your backend to get the data. It sounds like you're mostly doing that already though

Comment: oh..yeah, thats exactly what im doing.  My problem is that i have my spring-boot application dishing out a json response, but my angluar service (using the HttpClient http.get method) isn't displaying the json response in the component.html file

Comment: I can give you more info, if you think you can help

Comment: I use none of those technologies, so you can't help you there!