# Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1' from origin 'http://0.0.0.0:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: python, reactjs, docker-compose, cors, fastapi

This issue is well documented but my attempts have been unsuccessful... any suggestions are welcome!

- cookiecutter project on Github: [Buuntu/fastapi-react](https://github.com/Buuntu/fastapi-react)

### Recreating Error

```bash
cookiecutter gh:Buuntu/fastapi-react --no-input
cd fastapi-react-project
```

*modified files before running build script (in order to address prior errors):*

`frontend/Dockerfile`
line 7

```dockerfile
RUN npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

`docker-compose.yml`
line 37

```yaml
  # flower:
  #   image: mher/flower
  #   command: celery flower --broker=redis://redis:6379/0 --port=5555
  #   ports:
  #       - 5555:5555
  #   depends_on:
  #     - "redis"
```

```bash
cd fastapi-react-project
chmod +x scripts/build.sh
./scripts/build.sh
```

- open: http://0.0.0.0:8000/
- click: "Click to make request to backend"

> Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1' from origin 'http://0.0.0.0:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The request client is not a secure context and the resource is in more-private address space `local`.

> GET http://localhost:8000/api/v1 net::ERR_FAILED `api.ts:4` <-- fetch()

### Attempts

- [adding Access-Control-Allow-Origin to nginx](https://serverfault.com/questions/162429/how-do-i-add-access-control-allow-origin-in-nginx)
- [adding proxy to package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47902840/enabling-cors-in-create-react-app-utility)
- [adding no-cors to fetch()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61238680/access-to-fetch-at-from-origin-http-localhost3000-has-been-blocked-by-cors)
- [adding CORSMiddleware to FastAPI app](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/cors/?h=cors#use-corsmiddleware)

### System

```bash
➜ uname -v
# Darwin Kernel Version 21.6.0: Wed Aug 10 14:25:27 PDT 2022; root:xnu-8020.141.5~2/RELEASE_X86_64
➜ docker-compose version
# Docker Compose version v2.13.0
```

### Additional Info

- [nginx.conf](https://github.com/Buuntu/fastapi-react/blob/master/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.project_slug%7D%7D/nginx/nginx.conf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't open http://0.0.0.0:8000/ in your browser; open http://localhost:8000/ instead. That way the origin matches.

Comment: wow, not sure how I missed that one! this may be a dumb question but why are these two different?... [nevermind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778771/what-is-the-difference-between-0-0-0-0-127-0-0-1-and-localhost)

Comment: I'm honestly surprised that the browser even does `0.0.0.0:8000`; I'd been under the impression zero was just an alias for listening. Live and learn!

Comment: @will-wright-eng It's not a dumb question, there are no dumb question. Don't let toxic people stop you from asking questions. Just saw this but AKX was faster, good luck!