response gives an error when trying to run .json() on it
I have the following function in the nodejs language that serves as a server:
    async getAll(req, res, next) {
    try {
    const result = await this.service.getAll(req.query);
    return res.json(result);
    } catch (e) {
    next(e);
     }
    }

The function works fine when running, and when I open postman everything works fine, and I get an array of objects.
The problem:
When I want to access through a javascript page and get the array, I get an error, I access with this function:
  function Get() {
   fetch(`${basicUrl}`, { mode: 'no-cors' })
   .then((res) => {
   res.json();
   } )
   .then((data) => {
   printList(data);
   })
   .catch(err => { console.log("error" + err) });
   }

When I execute the code, I see on the side a server that did receive a request, and it returns a response.
But in the client, an error is thrown to me when I run the line: res.json();
The error I get is:

Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input (at
script.js:71:17)
at script.js:71:17

It doesn't let me do .json(),
I would really appreciate it if someone could direct me what the problem is

You can't read a response when using no-cors, also as a side note you use an explicit body on your  fetch()'s then() arrow function, explicit bodies need a return statement to pass on data eg { return res.json(); }

I changed the settings to not-cors because I got this error: home.html:1 access to retrieve at 'xxx/api/students/' from source 'null' was blocked by CORS policy: no header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
How can I bypass the error without defining the function as :not-cors?

Oh, I found the answer to my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70482133/23456704

@Patrick Evans Thank you, I didn't know the difference enough, you made me wise!
