# Connecting react native to nodejs back end

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api, react-native

Am trying to make a simple react native app that fetches the data from my express (nodejs app) and just simply show case it. 
the app works fine with api links I used from the web but for some reason when I use my own local server ( my own nodejs app) it doesn't show anything.

Am new to react native so I need your help.

This the code of my App.js ( from react native ) :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList } from "react-native";
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  state = {
    data: [],
  };

  fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("http://myipadress:5001/articles");
    const articles = await response.json();
    this.setState({ data: articles });
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>data</Text>

        <FlatList
          data={this.state.data}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <View
              style={{ backgroundColor: "#abc123", padding: 10, margin: 10 }}
            >
              <Text style={{ color: "#fff", fontWeight: "bold" }}>
                {item.title}
              </Text>

              <Text>{item.genre}</Text>
            </View>
          )}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#F5FCFF",
  },
});
```

and this is my api : that i access from the link http://myipadress:5001/articles :

```
[
    {
        "featured_media": {
            "source_url": "String",
            "caption": "String",
            "media_type": "String"
        },
        "categories": [
            "String"
        ],
        "tags": [
            "String"
        ],
        "_id": "5ea02d3d12d8153e34f779ca",
        "date": "2020-04-22T11:40:45.000Z",
        "title": "String",
        "excerpt": "String",
        "author": "String",
        "link": "String",
        "published_at": "2020-04-22T11:40:45.000Z",
        "content": "String",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

React native doesn't work with the same environment on local machine. 
You can try this code or axios. But as far as I know it doesn't work in the same local environment.

```
async () => {
    await fetch('http://myipadress:5001/articles')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => console.log(responseJson))
    .catch(err => console.log(err);

}
```

Comment: the code didn't work but i will check axios out thank you

Comment: Did u use await before this code and called it async

Comment: should i use the code like this :


fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(
      "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Hardeepcoder/fake_json/master/Users"
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => console.log(responseJson))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));

    this.setState({ data: response });
  };

Comment: If you are using promises in javascript you can setState in promises where u get the required data link in second .then. Read your console output like .then(responseJson) => setState({...state, data:responseJson})) in case you are using react hooks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem here is that you are trying to fetch from an HTTP endpoint which is your local server here. I used to have this problem when I was developing an app with Expo SDK. You can fix this by installing [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/download) which will expose an HTTPS endpoint for your local server.

Download ngrok and run `ngrok http 5001`or your port number on your terminal. ngrok will expose a HTTPS endpoint which you can use to fetch data.

```
fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("replace-with-new-ng-rk-url/articles");
    const articles = await response.json();
    this.setState({ data: articles });
  };
```

Comment: i exposed the port 5001 and changed the link inside fetch with the ngrok link/articles and for some reason it still returns nothing i also tried the same process for a diffrent server ( a movies api ) and it didnt work either

Comment: can you paste the link you got in the comment here, just to make sure?

Comment: This is the link i got from exposing the port 5001 using ngrok http 5001 : https://a51b95cd.ngrok.io/articles

Comment: Alright, can you log  `articles` after the line `const articles = await response.json();`

Comment: i get something like Access to fetch at 'https://a51b95cd.ngrok.io/articles' from origin 'https://localhost:19006' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: Can you take a look at the first answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43262121/trying-to-use-fetch-and-pass-in-mode-no-cors) ?